# CSS 100% height with padding/margin

Tags: css

With HTML/CSS, how can I make an element that has a width and/or height that is 100% of its parent element and still has proper padding or margins?

By "proper" I mean that if my parent element is `200px` tall and I specify `height = 100%` with `padding = 5px` I would expect that I should get a `190px` high element with `border = 5px` on all sides, nicely centered in the parent element.

Now, I know that that's not how the standard box model specifies it should work (although I'd like to know why, exactly...), so the obvious answer doesn't work:

```css
#myDiv {
    width: 100%
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

But it would seem to me that there must be SOME way of reliably producing this effect for a parent of arbitrary size. Does anyone know of a way of accomplishing this (seemingly simple) task?

Oh, and for the record I'm not interested in IE compatibility so that should (hopefully) make things a bit easier.

**EDIT:** Since an example was asked for, here's the simplest one I can think of:

```html
<html style="height: 100%">
    <body style="height: 100%">
        <div style="background-color: black; height: 100%; padding: 25px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The challenge is then to get the black box to show up with a 25-pixel padding on all edges without the page growing big enough to require scrollbars.

Comment: I've found these two solutions to be the most reliable: [http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/examples/csslayout1.html](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/examples/csslayout1.html) [http://themaninblue.com/experiment/footerStickAlt/](http://themaninblue.com/experiment/footerStickAlt/) Do you have any specific HTML that we can see and play with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931187/css-metaphysics-why-is-page-vertical-alignment-so-difficult

Answer (score 790, accepted):

I learned how to do these sort of things reading "[PRO HTML and CSS Design Patterns](http://cssdesignpatterns.com/)".  The `display:block` is the default display value for the `div`, but I like to make it explicit.  The container has to be the right type; `position` attribute is `fixed`, `relative`, or `absolute`.

```css
.stretchedToMargin {
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  height:auto;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  margin-right:80px;
  margin-left:80px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="stretchedToMargin">
  Hello, world
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rpdr9/) by Nooshu's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin#comment2356498_485887)

Comment: Wow... that's a lot of CSS to go through but it appears to work! This may be what I was looking for. Let me play around with it in a few more scenarios before I mark this as accepted.

Comment: If you have more questions, like how to get it to work in a particular context, let me know.  Note that the horizontal related elements and the vertical related elements can be used independently, so long as the display is block and position is fixed, absolute or relative.

Comment: Just tried it in the context that I'll be using it and it works like a charm. Still blown away that it takes that much code to do something that really ought to be two lines, but if it works I'll take it! Thanks!

Comment: Superb solution, will be bookmarking this one. Just quickly added it to http://jsfiddle.net/Rpdr9/ for anyone who wants a live demo. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Hmm actually I've come to prefer the book "CSS Mastery" by Andy Budd.  Both are worth reading though.  The patterns book has great information but the format is a pain.  CSS Mastery is the only reference I've found that shows how to seal of a region containing floats though.  Maybe its good to read both.

Comment: While @Toji didn't care about IE compatibility, I unfortunately have to. This solution didn't initially work under IE6. Adding Dean Edwards' [IE9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) to the page made this work. Now I just have to hope and pray that the relative/absolute positioning doesn't screw with something in a child element...

Comment: -1 (though it looks like I'm a minority here :P ). This assumes that the box can be absolutely-positioned; people already overuse pos:abs as it is, they don't need this ammo. Take this example: a div "panels" with multiple divs of class "panel" inside it. "panels" has {overflow:hidden; height:300px;}, and "panel" have varying contents/content-height, with {border:#000 solid 1px; float:left; margin-right:10px;}. Make all "panel" the height of "panels" without losing borders at any point. The "panel" divs cannot be pos:abs'd here. @Marco's solution works for this scenario, though.

Comment: I seem to have a unique issue. While this works for stretching a `<div>` to the size of a page with margins, it fails with padding. I wanted to have emulate frames by having a `<div>` along the left side that stretched to fill the page and had a border-right and a padding. Once the padding is applied it again stretches beyond the page, despite the `top:0; bottom:0;` rules.

Comment: Oh wow, I get it. The `top:0`, `bottom:0`, essentially "stretch" out the element. I can only get it to work with `position:absolute` though

Comment: I too can only get it to function when absolutely positioned but doing so messes up my float based layout. Is there a way to get full width/height divs including margins/paddings using floats?

Comment: Primus you'd need to provide examples about what is floating.  For the div in the example and its container, float is not an option.  If something outside or inside is floating, you may need to seal it off.  One way to seal float behavior is to wrap it in something with overflow:hidden or overflow:auto.

Comment: This breaks when content in `.stretchedToMargin` spans over height of 100%.

Comment: When the content is longer, I do see it rendered beyond the bottom of the div.  What would you prefer it to do?  Consider adding overflow:scroll or overflow:hidden.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `top:20px;bottom:20px;left:20px;right:20px;` instead of using margins at all?

Comment: Warning! This **will not work with SVG**. Tested on Chrome/webkit: http://jsfiddle.net/Thinkscape/UTMcn/

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work with `<textarea>` in most browsers. Only Chrome is good with it.

Comment: The '.stretchedToMargin' does not work with 'button' tags in Chrome v45 or Firefox v40. The button width does not stretch. http://jsfiddle.net/Rpdr9/2258/

Comment: `height: auto` is unnecessary, isn't it? And `* { box-sizing: border-box }` at the begining of your CSS is kind of a neccessity these days, so you don't need the `position: absolute`, which is often not possible anyway.

Comment: @s3c `box-sizing: border-box` doesn't support margin, and doesn't remove the need for `position: absolute` to get 100% height.

Answer (score 451):

There is a [new property in CSS3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#box-sizing) that you can use to change the way the box model calculates width/height, it's called box-sizing.

By setting this property with the value "border-box" it makes whichever element you apply it to not stretch when you add a padding or border. If you define something with 100px width, and 10px padding, it will still be 100px wide.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

[See here for browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing). It does not work for IE7 and lower, however, I believe that Dean Edward's [IE7.js](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/notes/) adds support for it. Enjoy :)

Comment: Finally! I've been waiting for this exact feature for about 10 years now. Pity IE7 doesnt support it but I always think people who are still using IE dont deserve a beautiful layout.

Comment: This worked on iPhone/Safari and Android's default browser for me whereas the absolutely positioned solution above did not work.

Comment: This is basically the same as [IE's quirks mode box model](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/about-boxmodel.htm). I find it funny how everyone hates on IE yet now `border-box` is everyone's hero :)

Comment: but ... quirks mode was the only good about IE ;-) ... thanks for posting this solution, this is EXACTLY, what i was looking for.

Comment: FYI, the browser prefix for box-sizing is now dropped for all but -moz.  See http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ and the comments for a good discussion

Comment: Yes! This is the right answer! 100% height now scales things correctly relative to their parents, without spilling over. Would give a million +1's if I could.

Comment: Very minor point (to an older answer).  This works with padding, but not margins.  Margins are outside the border.  Still very useful to me.  Thanks!

Comment: this is supported by all major browsers, without the prefixes: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Answer (score 72):

The solution is to NOT use height and width at all! Attach the inner box using top, left, right, bottom and then add margin.

```css
.box {margin:8px; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background:black">
  <div class="box" style="background:green">
    <div class="box" style="background:lightblue">
      This will show three nested boxes. Try resizing browser to see they remain nested properly.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Up-vote because you're technically correct, but it's also basically the same answer as Frank's (Which I think is a bit more friendly to the sloppier browsers out there.)

Comment: @Toji But this answer is more concise and also follows the example from the question more closely (it has the nested elements, which is important here).

Answer (score 54):

The better way is with the `calc()` property. So, your case would look like:

```css
#myDiv {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    height: calc(100% - 10px);
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Simple, clean, no workarounds. Just make sure you don't forget the space between the values and the operator (eg `(100%-5px)` that will break the syntax. Enjoy!

Comment: Nice solution. Just remember to check browser support: [Can I use calc()](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: Wouldn't this actually give you 100% width and height each PLUS 5px padding, since the padding would  effectively make the element 10px wider and larger, respectively?

Comment: Finally a good solution, and not like the rest of them there you pot the top,
 right, bottom and left to be 0, that will work only with position: absolute;

Comment: I think the correct is: #myDiv {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    height: calc(100% - 10px);
    padding: 5px;
}

5 from left and 5 from right = 10,
5 from top and 5 from bottom = 10

Answer (score 21):

According the w3c spec height refers to the height of the viewable area e.g. on a 1280x1024 pixel resolution monitor 100% height = 1024 pixels.

min-height refers to the total height of the page including content so on a page where the content is bigger than 1024px min-height:100% will stretch to include all of the content.

The other problem then is that padding and border are added to the height and width in most modern browsers except ie6(ie6 is actually quite logical but does not conform to the spec). This is called the box model. So if you specify

```
min-height: 100%;
padding: 5px;
```

It will actually give you 100% + 5px + 5px for the height. To get around this you need a wrapper container.

```html
<style>
    .FullHeight { 
       height: auto !important; /* ie 6 will ignore this */
       height: 100%;            /* ie 6 will use this instead of min-height */
       min-height: 100%;        /* ie 6 will ignore this */
    }

    .Padded {
       padding: 5px;
    }
</style>

<div class="FullHeight">
   <div class="Padded">
      Hello i am padded.
   </div
</div>
```

Comment: @Alex: But what makes the inner div (the Padded one) 100% of the outer div's height.  My experience has been that you just get a little short div inside a larger full-height div.

Answer (score 9):

**1. Full height with `padding`**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Hello world.</div>
```

**2. Full height with `margin`**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  margin: 50px;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Hello world.</div>
```

**3. Full height with `border`**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 50px solid pink;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Hello world.</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

This is one of the outright idiocies of CSS - I have yet to understand the reasoning (if someone knows, pls. explain).

100% means 100% of the container height - to which any margins, borders and padding are added.  So it is effectively impossible to get a container which fills it's parent and which has a margin, border, or padding.

Note also, setting height is notoriously inconsistent between browsers, too.

---

Another thing I've learned since I posted this is that the percentage is relative the container's *length*, that is, it's width, making a percentage even more worthless for height.

Nowadays, the vh and vw viewport units are more useful, but still not especially useful for anything other than the top-level containers.

Comment: There is no reasoning, just what happened where browsers started to converge towards consistent behavior.  Check out the book mentioned in my response.

Comment: Upvoted for using the right term. Tex and any layout manager I've seen got it right, just CSS must be special.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to use display:table which has a different box model behaviour.

You can set a height and width to the parent and add padding without expanding it. The child has 100% height and width minus the paddings.

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/usudef/1/)

Another option would be to use box-sizing propperty. Only problem with both would be they dont work in IE7.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution:  You can use percentage units for margins as well as sizes.  For example:

```
.fullWidthPlusMargin {
    width: 98%;
    margin: 1%;
}
```

The main issue here is that the margins will increase/decrease slightly with the size of the parent element.  Presumably the functionality you would prefer is for the margins to stay constant and the child element to grow/shrink to fill changes in spacing.  So, depending on how tight you need your display to be, that could be problematic.  (I'd also go for a smaller margin, like 0.3%).

Answer (score 4):

A solution with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (working on IE11): ([or view on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLkj56fg/8/))

```
<html>
  <style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%; /* fix for IE11, not needed for chrome/ff */
      margin: 0; /* CSS-reset for chrome */
    }
  </style>
  <body style="display: flex;">
    <div style="background-color: black; flex: 1; margin: 25px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

(The [CSS-reset](https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/) is not necessarily important for the actual problem.)

The important part is `flex: 1` (In combination with `display: flex` at the parent). Funnily enough, the most plausible explanation I know for how the Flex property works comes from a react-native documentation, [so I refer to it anyway](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html#flex-dimensions):

> (...) flex: 1, which tells a component to fill all available space, shared evenly amongst other components with the same parent

Answer (score 4):

To add -webkit and -moz would be more appropriate

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 2):

Frank's example confused me a bit - it didn't work in my case because I didn't understand positioning well enough yet. It's important to note that the parent container element needs to have a non-static position (he mentioned this but I overlooked it, and it wasn't in his example).

Here's an example where the child - given padding and a border - uses absolute positioning to fill the parent 100%. The parent uses relative positioning in order to provide a point of reference for the child's position while remaining in the normal flow - the next element "more-content" is not affected:

```css
#box {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
}

#box p {
    position: absolute;
    border-style: dashed;
    padding: 1em;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <p>100% height and width!</p>
</div>
<div id="more-content">
</div>
```

A useful [link](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) for quickly learning CSS positioning

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior of `display: block` The fastest way that you can fix it in 2020 is to set `display: 'flex'` of parent element and padding e.g. 20px then all its children will have 100% height relative to its height.

Answer (score 0):

#### Border around div, rather than page body margin

Another solution - I just wanted a simple border around the edge of my page, and I wanted 100% height when the content was smaller than that.

Border-box didn't work, and the fixed positioning seemed wrong for such a simple need.

I ended up adding a border to my container, instead of relying on the margin of the body of the page - it looks like this :

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 8px solid #564333;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  <style type="text/css">
.stretchedToMargin {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}
</style>
```