# Can I stop 100% Width Text Boxes from extending beyond their containers?

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have a text box that I want to fill a whole line. I would give it a style like this:

```
input.wide {display:block; width: 100%}
```

This causes problems because the width is based on the content of the text box. Text boxes have margin, borders, & padding by default, which makes a 100% width text box larger than its container.

For example, here on the right:

[image]

Is there any way to make a text box fill the width of its container without expanding beyond it?

Here is some example HTML to show what I mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #outer{border: 1px solid #000; width: 320px; margin: 0px;padding:0px}
        #inner{margin: 20px; padding: 20px; background: #999;border: 1px solid #000;}
        input.wide {display:block; margin: 0px}
        input.normal {display:block; float: right}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
            <input type="text" class="wide" />
            <input type="text" class="normal" />
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If this is run, you can see by looking at the "normal" text box that the "wide" text box is sticking out beyond the container. The "normal" text box floats to the actual edge of the container. I'm trying to make the "wide" text box fill its container, without expanding beyond edge like the "normal" text box is.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

What you could do is to remove the default "extras" on the `input`:

```
input.wide {display:block; width:100%;padding:0;border-width:0}
```

This will keep the `input` inside its container.
Now if you do want the borders, wrap the `input` in a `div`, with the borders set on the `div` (that way you can remove the `display:block` from the `input` too). Something like:

```
<div style="border:1px solid gray;">
 <input type="text" class="wide" />
</div>
```

**Edit:**
Another option is to, instead of removing the style from the `input`, compensate for it in the wrapped `div`:

```
input.wide {width:100%;}

<div style="padding-right:4px;padding-left:1px;margin-right:2px">
  <input type="text" class="wide" />
</div>
```

This will give you somewhat different results in different browsers, but they will not overlap the container. The values in the div depend on how large the border is on the `input` and how much space you want between the `input` and the border.

Comment: This is a very creative solution. The only issue I have with it is that I can't define an outline on the text box when it gains focus unless I use JavaScript to change the border of the wrapper div.

Comment: @DanHerbert, you're right, that's a major UX flaw of this method

Answer (score 292):

> Is there any way to make a text box fill the width of its container without expanding beyond it?

Yes: by using the CSS3 property ‘box-sizing: border-box’, you can redefine what ‘width’ means to include the external padding and border.

Unfortunately because it's CSS3, support isn't very mature, and as the spec process isn't finished yet, it has different temporary names in browsers in the meantime. So:

```
input.wide {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The old-school alternative is simply to put a quantity of ‘padding-right’ on the enclosing <div> or <td> element equal to about how much extra left-and-right padding/border in ‘px’ you think browsers will give the input. (Typically 6px for IE<8.)

Comment: This would work great, except can't use this because I'm targeting mobile devices which probably won't support this for years. :-\

Comment: I think mobile devices will have full HTML5 support before computers.

Comment: @Kindred: definitely not if you include IEMobile and Blackberry in that.

Comment: This has great support for desktop browsers, though: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: great, but how do you make fall back option in case the browser does not support CSS3?

Comment: You could also add a text-indent which would give you padding on the left. But this won't work for padding on the right or textareas.

Comment: actually as you can see it is supported by almost everything.. http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

Comment: Thank you, this is a huge help for responsive layouts.

Comment: How did it take me this long to find this awesome buttersauce??? Can we please make this the accepted answer?

Comment: border-box is now the correct solution. This should now be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 23):

This solved the problem for me!

**Without the need for an external div.** Just apply it to your given text box.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

With this property "The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin"

See description of property at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Wonderfully simple!  Thx!

Answer (score 10):

Just came across this problem myself, and the only solution I could find that worked in all my test browsers (IE6, IE7, Firefox) was the following:

1. Wrap the input field in two separate DIVs
2. Set the outer DIV to width 100%, this prevents our container from overflowing the document
3. Put padding in the inner DIV of the exact amount to compensate for the horizontal overflow of the input.
4. Set custom padding on the input so it overflows by the same amount as I allowed for in the inner DIV

The code:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
    <div style="padding-right: 6px;">
        <input type="text" style="width: 100%; padding: 2px; margin: 0;
                                  border : solid 1px #999" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, the total horizontal overflow for the input element is 6px - 2x(padding + border) - so we set a padding-right for the inner DIV of 6px.

Comment: add to the input element a 8px padding and it doesnt work anymore

Answer (score 7):

box-sizing support is pretty good actually: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

So unless you target IE7, you should be able to solve this kind of issues using this property. A layer such as sass or less makes it easier to handle prefixed rules like that, btw.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's because CSS defines 100% relative to the entire width of the container, including its margins, borders, and padding; that means that the space avail. to its contents is some amount smaller than 100%, unless the container has no margins, borders, or padding.

*This is counter-intuitive and widely regarded by many to be a mistake that we are now stuck with*.  It effectively means that % dimensions are no good for anything other than a top level container, and even then, only if it has no margins, borders or padding.

Note that the text field's margins, borders, and padding *are* included in the CSS size specified for it - it's the container's which throw things off.

I have tolerably worked around it by using 98%, but that is a less than perfect solution, since the input fields tend to fall further short as the container gets larger.

---

EDIT: I came across this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin) - I've never tried the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin/485838#485838) given, and I don't know for sure if it applies to your problem, but it seems like it will.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that may work (it works for me) is to apply **negative margin at input (textbox)**... or fixed width for ie7 or to drop ie7 support.
This results to pixel perfect width.. For me its 7 so i added 3 and 4 but it is still pixel perfect..

I had the same problem and i hated to have extra divs for border etc!

So here is my solution which seems to work!

You should use a ie7 only stylesheet to avoid the starhacks.

```
input.text{
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    border : solid #eee 1px;
    width: 100%;
    -box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;

    *line-height:32px;
    *margin-left:-3px;
    *margin-right:-4px;
    display: inline;   
    padding: 0px 0 0 5px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `box-sizing:border-box` you could try removing the `width:100%` and putting a very large `size` attribute in the `<input>` element, drawback is however you have to modify the html, and can't do it with CSS only:

```
<input size="1000"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do it dynamically (for example, your form is of a fixed width) you can just set the width of child `<input>` elements to the width of their container minus any decorations like padding, margin, border, etc.:

```
 // the parent div here has a width of 200px:
.form-signin input[type="text"], .form-signin input[type="password"], .form-signin input[type="email"], .form-signin input[type="number"] {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 280px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 7px 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use box-sizing (e.g. when you convert HTML to PDF using iText). Try this:

CSS

```
.input-wrapper { border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 0 5px; min-height: 20px; } 
.input-wrapper input[type=text] { border: none; height: 20px; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
     <input type="text" value="" name="city"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" 
        style="margin: 5px; padding: 4px; border: 1px solid; 
        width: 200px; width: calc(100% - 20px);">
</div>
```

The first 'width' is a fallback rule for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Just style the input to offset for the extra padding.  In the following example the padding on the input would be 10px on the left and right for a total padding offset of 20px:

```
input[type=text]{
   width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```