# CSS: how to set the width of form control so they all have the same width?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border-box

Consider the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            div { width: 15em }
            input, textarea, select { width: 100%;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div>
                <input value="Input">
            </div>
            <div>
                <textarea>Text area</textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select>
                    <option>One</option>
                    <option>Two</option>
                    <option>Three</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

On browser that support the `border-box` box sizing, this is rendered as I want:

[Correct rendering http://img.skitch.com/20100522-c75mhdut2q32yc7u5r2tkft1n4.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100522-c75mhdut2q32yc7u5r2tkft1n4.png)

On IE 6/7, however, this is rendered as:

[IE 6/7 rendering http://img.skitch.com/20100522-f5pkgnwwceaak3t8fqq2w16gfm.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100522-f5pkgnwwceaak3t8fqq2w16gfm.png)

How can I get the same rendering in IE 6/7 that I get in other browsers, without resorting to setting sizes in pixels?

Comment: Mind if I suggest cross-posting this question to http://doctype.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with CSS. I did some research and I found out that the same question was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030793/input-with-displayblock-is-not-a-block-why-not). The solution is to use this [boxsizing.htc](http://www.test.dev.arc.net.au/boxsizing.htc) file and add the following line to your HTML head:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><style>input, textarea { behavior: url("boxsizing.htc"); }</style><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use CSS and JavaScript to replace form controls that browser vendors have conspired to make a pain to style.  A select is just a drop down menu with an onmouseup event.  JS-driven text editors (rich and simple) which can replace a textarea abound online.  There are even libs just for this purpose. ([Example](http://www.lexcat.ro/nicejforms/nicejforms.html))

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix could be to IE6/7 browser-hack it with something like `select { *width:102.5%; _width:102.5%; }` though this may not line up to the pixel if too wide.

Comment: The problem with this, is that it locks you to a given font size. Let's say I add a `select { *width:102.5% }`. Perfect, now the form fields have the same width: http://img.skitch.com/20100522-ght27dws54jqp8r79bf5nf1hus.png. But now add a `body { font-size: 200% }`. With the same `select { *width:102.5% }`, you get: http://img.skitch.com/20100522-ksie3bm45e83g314869fdhby29.png. So that percentage you put in `select { *width:102.5% }` would depend on the font size. As your font size changes, you'll need to go change that percentage. Rather than this, I'd prefer to go with a width in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you: [CSS3 support for Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8](http://www.fetchak.com/ie-css3/). From the page:

> IE-CSS3 is a script to provide
>   Internet Explorer support for several
>   of the popular new styles available in
>   the upcoming CSS3 standard.

Comment: Unfortunately, this `htc` doesn't include support for `box-sizing`.