# What is it in the CSS/DOM that prevents an input box with display: block from expanding to the size of its container

Tags: css

### Sample HTML/CSS:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" />
    <div class="filler"></div>
</div>

div.container {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: gray;
}

div.filler {
    background-color: red;
    height: 5px;
}

input {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bPEkb/3/

### Question

Why doesn't the input box expand to have the same outer width as, say `div.filler`? That is to say, why doesn't the input box expand to fit its container like other block elements with `width: auto;` do?

I tried checking the "User Agent CSS" in Firebug to see if I could come up with something there. No luck. I couldn't find any specific differences in CSS that I could specifically link to the input box behaving differently from the regular `div.filler`.

Besides curiousity, I'd like to know why this is to get to the bottom of it to figure out a way to set width once and forget it. My current practice of explicitly setting the width of both `input` and its containing block element seems redundant and less than modular. While I'm familiar with the technique of wrapping the input element in a div then assigning to the input element negative margins, this seems quite undesirable.

borkweb and Phrogz have both provided exceptional information that takes advantage of the `border-box` box model from the old days. Thanks for this! I'd like to reiterate the focus of my question that I intend to keep distinct from the [proposed solution to my practical problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030793/input-with-displayblock-is-not-a-block-why-not):

**What about the specification causes input boxes to be formatted unlike ordinary block elements like `div`s? The border-box solution is wonderful, but it doesn't satisfy the desire to figure out why input boxes are this way in the first place and why they can't be made to behave exactly like ordinary `div`s, which do not use the border-box model these days.**

Comment: besides http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#block I'ld question what does `width:auto;` imply in this situation? It doesn't imply "full parent width"

Comment: @drachenstern: I concede that my understanding of `width: auto;` is shotty at best. I've only ever used it when trying to force a non-floated block element to take up the rest of the container width next to a floated element. I'll remove it to avoid confusion in this case, although it seems not to make a difference.

Comment: It doesn't, because `width: auto;` is generally the default setting. There's reasons to use it in a stylesheet, but in this case I'm almost certain that what you _want_ is `width: 100%;`

Comment: @drachenstern: Please see my below comment on why `width: 100%` is insufficient because it sets the `input` width to the inner width of the container, and subsequent padding and borders will be in excess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [input with display:block is not a block, why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030793/input-with-displayblock-is-not-a-block-why-not)

Comment: @Phrogz: Thanks for the link. That solution is definitely more satisfying than my DOM hack. To the question of closing this one, the main predicates of the questions are different: I am asking, above all, what about the specification causes this sort of behaviour in the input box; the linked post just asks for a way to solve it. I will reword my question to make this very distinct objective clear.

Comment: @StevenXu Understood and agreed. I want to know, too. :) Some things I saw on my search lead me to believe that it may be related to the fact that the default is `width:auto` but what that means might vary. _(Why or where this is codified, I don't know.)_

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Alright, due to the clarification of the original question...I did some digging and found [these laments](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/15/formal-weirdness/) and [this article](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements).

There are a few elements (`<input>, <select>, <button>, <img>, <object>, and <textarea>`) that are considered **replaced elements** whose appearance and dimensions are defined by an external resource. (e.g. the operating system, a plugin, etc)

> Replaced elements can have intrinsic
>   dimensions—width and height values
>   that are defined by the element
>   itself, rather than by its
>   surroundings in the document. For
>   example, if an image element has a
>   width set to auto, the width of the
>   linked image file will be used.
>   Intrinsic dimensions also define an
>   intrinsic ratio that’s used to
>   determine the computed dimensions of
>   the element should only one dimension
>   be specified. For example, if only the
>   width is specified for an image
>   element—at, say, 100px—and the actual
>   image is 200 pixels wide and 100
>   pixels high, the height of the element
>   will be scaled by the same amount, to
>   50px.
>
> Replaced elements can also have visual 
>   formatting requirements imposed by the 
>   element, outside of the control of CSS; 
>   for example, the user interface controls 
>   rendered for form elements.

W3C's CSS 2.1 "Visual Formatting Model Details" section [discusses](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins) the calculation of widths of both replaced and non-replaced elements.

Overall...pretty annoying for some form elements (`<textarea>, <button>, and <input>`).  Can/will it change?  Probably not any time soon...Until it does change at the core, we'll have to stick with the hacks :(

Comment: Thanks for this, borkweb. I have familiarized myself with replaced elements, but I had no clue that input elements belonged in this category. In retrospect, this still doesn't make any sense. Links: [definition of replaced element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html); [width of inline replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width). I'd like to dig a bit further into options with the `box-sizing` declaration; perhaps there is a value that forces non-replaced element-like behaviour.

Comment: Upon [further inspection](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing) as well as your other sources, it doesn't seem feasible at this moment (although it does explain why I've never gotten line-height to work in input boxes). Among the non-JS/Flash options of replacing input text boxes with editable divs, wrapping them in containing divs, and using `border-box`, it seems like the last one is the best if only to maintain DOM structure.

Comment: One of the articles I linked to in the above post (http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/15/formal-weirdness/) discusses some of the reasons behind form elements acting as replaced elements.  It is weird, however, at least there seems to be some very small amount of sanity behind it. :/

Comment: I've reviewed the article, and it's really highly unconvincing. Total conversion plugins like jQueryMobile amply demonstrate that non-replaced input quasi-elements can fully take the place of the current replaced elements. I do understand, however, the need for legacy support and will come to accept it. It truly would be a shame though if these same replaced elements fully make their way into the HTML5 specification.

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish this by making use of the box-sizing CSS property on the input box:

```
input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* CSS3 */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox */
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box; /* IE8 */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari */
    -khtml-box-sizing: border-box; /* Konqueror */
}
```

Additionally, to get it to work with IE6 & IE7, you'll need to throw this in your HTML:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><style>input{behavior:url("boxsizing.htc");}</style><![endif]-->
```

See it in action, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EWvZP/).

Get the boxsizing.htc [here](http://code.google.com/p/alageospatialportal/source/browse/trunk/alaspatial/src/main/webapp/slider/css/boxsizing.htc?spec=svn50&r=50).

[SpliFF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108741/spliff)'s [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030793/input-with-displayblock-is-not-a-block-why-not/1033745#1033745) was my source a while back and I've used it a couple times since.

Comment: As the comments clearly indicate, he's trying to NOT use the `width: 100%;` setting and he has a padding on the parent element, causing the width to be miscalculated. Additionally, I doubt CSS3 is on his plate.

Comment: Yeah...I saw that.  Why an input's width fails to function like a block element - with regards to width - is beyond me, however, the above solution allows one to use width: 100% without the width actually being miscalculated.  In other words, it forces the input element to function like a typical block level element.

Comment: so apparently the word is that input elements have a different internal box model ...

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's a wonderful solution to my practical problem, but I'm afraid the initial question I posed remains unresolved :(.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the default length of the input text field is 20 characters.

I guess that's the value it gets when you set it to **auto**. Usually it is not useful to have a text field of the size of width of the screen, that's why I guess it defaults to 20 characters in **auto**.

Anyway, it should be better to check the w3c standard, or get a response from some browser developer.

Comment: I looked at the w3c on this one, and there's nothing about the width defined (or I missed it)

Comment: Yeah, I just checked there, but I cannot find any reference. But I'm totally sure that the default value is 20. I guess that comes from the browser vendors, if not w3c. Anyone with a friend in Mozilla?

Comment: @Christian, I think you're talking about the `<input>` element's `size` attribute, which does indeed default to `20` (characters): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Answer (score 0):

if you want that the input element has the same width as div.filter, and if div.filter has the same width of div.container you can set width: 100% on input box.

Comment: `width: 100%` only adjusts the inner width of the input box. Doing so very clearly makes the input element's outer width [exceed](http://jsfiddle.net/bPEkb/1/) the inner width of the containing div. Thus the question.

Comment: @StevenXu It's because of the padding on the previous container. Try this for playing with http://jsfiddle.net/bPEkb/4/

Comment: Thanks very much for your contribution, but I'm afraid this doesn't accomplish much. So long as `width: 100%`, the input box can't take a border or padding lest it exceed the inner width of the containing div. Sure, you can add a negative left margin (your negative right margin doesn't do much here) and center the difference, but the matter remains that you still have an `input` with an outer width wider than the containing `div.container`. I have made the issue abundantly clear here: http://jsfiddle.net/bPEkb/4/

Comment: @StevenXu I saw the "abundantly clear" reason there, and the options are _either_ a) find the target width using javascript and setting the width of the textbox that way, or b) the way I demonstrated with negative margins. My negative margin hack was just that, a hack. I just wanted to demonstrate the fact that it _could_ be done from the CSS. If I needed it to be the width of the internal, I would set it with javascript. Sorry.

Comment: The superior "hack" might be to include a containing div with positive margins equal to the sum of the padding+border.

Answer (score 0):

I have some findings on newly HTML spec:

1. `<input type="text">` elements are non-replaced elements.

   [MDN:replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)
2. `<input type="text">` should adjust the `width` according to its `size` attribute by default, if it does not have `size` attribute (unlimited input length), adjust `width` with 20 characters:

   [HTML 5.2:The input element as a text entry widget](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/rendering.html#the-input-element-as-a-text-entry-widget)

   [HTML Living Standard:The input element as a text entry widget](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#the-input-element-as-a-text-entry-widget)

   > If an input element whose **type** attribute is in one of the above states(**Text, Search, Telephone, URL, or E-mail**) **has a size attribute**, and parsing that attribute's value using the rules for parsing non-negative integers doesn't generate an error, then the user agent is expected to use the attribute as a presentational hint for the '**width**' property on the element, with the value obtained from applying the converting a character width to pixels algorithm to the value of the attribute.
   >
   > If an input element whose type attribute is in one of the above states **does not have a size attribute**, then the user agent is expected to act as if it had a user-agent-level style sheet rule setting the '**width**' property on the element to the value obtained from applying the converting a character width to pixels algorithm to the number **20**.

Answer (score 0):

- In my HTML I have a `<ul>` menu...

  - where some `<li>` elements have `<button>` content.
  - some other `<li>` elements have `<label>` content (wrapping a checkbox and `<span>`).
  - and most remaining `<li>` elements have a child-menu as their content.
- I'm having the same problem as [an old duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605390/why-doesnt-display-block-width-auto-stretch-a-button-to-fill-the-contai) post: where it's a `<button>` element that has *seemingly identical* computed-styles as the `li > label` elements and yet the final rendered layout width of the `<button>` is awkwardly different.

  - My stylesheet already specifies these style properties on the `<button>` elements in-question *and* the `li > label` elements, so they *should* be rendered the same... except they aren't:

    - `appearance: none;`

      - (so it *shouldn't* have any native or replaced button style or layout... right?)
    - `display: block;`
    - `box-sizing: border-box;`
    - `width: 100%;`
    - `margin: 0.2em;`
    - `padding: 0.3em 0.5em;`
    - `border: none;`
    - `border-radius: 5px;`
- This is how it looks in Firefox and Chrome. (I've used the "force `:hover`" tool to show the teal `background-color` of two of the `<li>` children to show the effective size of the elements:

  - In this case, see how the top `<li>`'s `<button>` is akwardly *ever-so-slightly* wider than the other list items:

    - [image]
- If I set `width: auto;` on the `<button>` then the `<button>` shrinks width in-place and looks like this:

  - [image]
  - ...however, setting `width: auto;` on `li > label` has no effect.
  - Therefore there is *something inherent* in `<button>` give it a different final layout compared to `<label>` even when all style properties are the same. *Weird*.
- Here's a screenshot showing the same `li > button`, `li > label`, etc elements with `outline: 1px solid red; border: 1px solid blue;` set - the awkward size different is *palpable*:

  - [image]

---

- After some experimentation I stumbled upon `width: -webkit-fill-available;` in Chrome's WebInspector's list of supported values for `width:` and to my surprise **it works:**.

  - [image]
- However `-webkit-fill-available` has that *dreaded vendor prefix*, so what's a good, vendor-neutral, well-supported, solution?

  - ...[according to caniuse.com there still isn't yet a finalized CSS specification](https://caniuse.com/?search=fill-available) version of `width: -webkit-fill-available`, hence all the synonyms and vendor-prefixes still.
  - So as of September 2022, try this:

    ```css
    button {
        appearance: none;
        display: block;
        font-family: inherit;

        width: -webkit-fill-available; /* Chromium/Blink 46 to 108 and beyond */
        width: -moz-available; /* Firefox 66 to 106 and beyond */
        width: stretch; /* Safari/WebKit 11 and beyond */
    }
    ```