# How do I make an input element occupy all remaining horizontal space?

Tags: html, css

Here's the code:

```
<div style="width:400px">
    some text..
    <input type="text" />
    <button value="click me" />
</div>
```

How can I make the input element expand to fill all the remaining space, while staying on the same line?
If I put 100% it goes to a line of its own...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/rQ3xG/466/

This works in IE7+ and all modern browsers.

```css
.formLine {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ccc;
}
.formLine input {
    width: 100%;
}
.formLine label {
    float: left;
}
.formLine span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
.formLine button {
    float: right;
}
.formLine input, .formLine button {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="formLine">
    <button>click me</button>
    <label>some text.. </label>
    <span><input type="text" /></span>
</div>
```

The `button` must go first in the HTML. Slightly distasteful, but c'est la vie.

The key step is using `overflow: hidden;`: why this is necessary is explained at:

- http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats
- [How does the CSS Block Formatting Context work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work)

The extra span around `input` is necessary because `display:block;` has no effect for `input`: [What is it in the CSS/DOM that prevents an input box with display: block from expanding to the size of its container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567988/what-is-it-in-the-css-dom-that-prevents-an-input-box-with-display-block-from-ex)

Comment: There's your +1 I promised yesterday :)

Comment: `box-sizing` is not supported by IE7 and below.

Comment: @pixelfreak: True, but the use of `box-sizing` here is not strictly necessary, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Very helpful! Why is it that the button must go first?

Comment: @ThomasDavidBaker: The element that's floated right must be before the element with overflow hidden, otherwise it breaks.

Comment: @thirtydot Haha, sorry I wasn't very clear.  I understand that it's necessary to work.  I was curious as to *why* it was necessary.

Comment: Vertical alignment of the label anyone?

Comment: @thirtydot `overflow:hidden` seems to be doing a big part of the magic, otherwise the block element would move to the next line. Any explanation for this? thx

Comment: @AdrienBe: [Here you go.](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, isn't a `<span>` with `display: block;` functionally identical to a `<div>`? The example you have seems to work with either, at least in chrome, opera and firefox (I don't have IE installed).

Comment: @FakeName: Yes, they are the same. Take your pick.

Comment: I wanted to avoid a flexbox approach as I thought "that's too much for just that", but this is even more cumbersome !

Comment: @rvighne: I like the edit, but you removed the note about the `button` having to go first in the HTML. People inevitably try to move the `button` to the end, then become confused when it doesn't work.

Comment: @thirtydot Whoops, sorry about that. I missed it because it was between two code blocks :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want a cross-browser decision you can use table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" /></td>
    <td><button value="click me" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you can't use table it would be more difficult.
For instance, if you know exactly the width of the some text you can try this way:

```
<div style="padding:0px 60px 0px 120px;">
  <div style="width:120px; float:left; margin:0px 0px 0px -120px;">some text</div>
  <input type="button" style="width:50px; float:right; margin:0px -55px 0px 0px;" />
  <input type="text" style="width:100%;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about old browsers support (IE <= 9) use a [flexbox layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```
div{
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div input {
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex:1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    -moz-flex: 1;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```