# Label/input fixed-fluid layout in forms

Tags: css, forms, layout, fluid-layout

I am trying to solve the problem presented in this [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378848/fluid-label-input-aka-2-column-fixfluid-possilbe). Basically, I would like to create a form where a labels and related inputs are on the same line. Labels have a fixed width and inputs extend for the remaining form width. Each label + input couple has its own line.

```
<form>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input id="name"/>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input id="email"/>
</form>
```

I've read the solution proposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189608/how-do-i-make-an-input-element-occupy-all-remaining-horizontal-space/7190310#7190310) but I doesn't convince me much. I think it's not very semantic, because it introduces a `formLine` class. I may be super-fussy, but I think that HTML code should only contain semantic stuff (in this case `label` and `input`) and layout should be left to stylesheet only.

Does anybody have a clue to style the snippet above without adding not-semantic code? I think the key should be to tell `input` to occupy the remaining line space, to avoid to use something like `<br/>` after each input.

Comment: take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/zU9Xv/284/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this behaviour without changing your example markup by using the CSS `calc();` function:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/aK85c/)**

```
label{
    display:inline-block;
    width:95px;
}
input{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: This is nice. I thought about it, but unfortunately calc is not supported from IE8: [link](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc). Anyway this can be a hyper-fussy objection and your answer is very good.

Comment: @Giorgio yes, the support even though pretty good doesn't go that far... you can do this without the `calc()` function but it involves wrapping the input inside a span element witch doesn't seem to be your aim.

Comment: Yep, you are right again @web-tiki. I think your answer is the best solution for my problem and I'll accept it. Maybe I'll style labels and inputs as blocks for IE8 users only (I think no IE8-users would complain about it, eheh).