# Input text auto width filling 100% with other elements floating

Tags: html, css, css-float

i have the following layout for a search box with:

```
<div id="emulating_variable_width">
  <form id="srxForm" method="post">
     <div id="qsrxSearchbar">            
         <div id="scope"> Person Name </div>
         <input type="text" id="theq" title="Search">
         <button id="btnSearch" type="button">Search</button>
      </div>
  </form>    
</div>​
```

(its very much simplified for showing purposes)

- The title in the 'scope' is a text that can be variable in length

What i will like is to have the input text element to fill all available space (i.e. yellow space), while keeping the search button at the right.

[Full example with the CSS is in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7YTT/)

Which would be the easiest way to accomplish a solution working in IE7+,FF,Safari,etc...  ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is JQuery not an option?

Comment: I would prefer not using jQuery here, although if there is no other option... yeah

Comment: Use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7190310/405015

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Like this?

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/v7YTT/19/**

HTML:

```
<div id="emulating_variable_width">
   <form id="srxForm" method="post">
       <div id="qsrxSearchbar"> 
           <button id="btnSearch">Search</button>             
           <label id="scope"> Person Name </label>
           <span><input type="text" id="theq" title="Search" /></span>
      </div>
   </form> 
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#qsrxSearchbar
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#qsrxSearchbar input
{
    width: 100%
}

#qsrxSearchbar label
{
    float: left
}

#qsrxSearchbar span 
{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 5px
}

#qsrxSearchbar button 
{
    float: right
}

#qsrxSearchbar input, .formLine button
{ 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

​

Comment: Wohoho! looks like working! but i'm not sure what's the purpose of the last style, the boz-sizing for this example, is that necessary? Tanks a lot

Comment: Not really necessary, it was more of a "just-in-case" usage, it will work without. Making sure everything will fit side by side in all browsers :).

Comment: You could have at least upvoted my answer if you're going to "repost" it like this.. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @jmserra: The point of `box-sizing: border-box` is to make sure the `input` fits exactly into the containing `span`. For example, if there's a lot of `padding` or `border` on the `input`: [with `box-sizing: border-box`](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/v7YTT/21/) vs [without](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/v7YTT/22/).

Comment: @thirtydot I would of, but I'm maxed out votes today! I will tomorrow :). I didn't "repost" your answer, I merely applied your logic to the given solution :) hehe

Comment: is there a limit of up votings? i had no idea

Comment: Yeah lol, 40 in 24 hours, try it, you'll earn the Vox Populi badge :)

Comment: This code works, but "span { display: block }" shows a large misunderstanding of HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

hey you can used focus properties in input field as like this

**Css**

```
    #emulating_variable_width{
    width:500px;

    height:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
input {
    width:auto;
    /*width:100%;*/
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
#scope{float:left;}
button{float:left;}

input:focus{
width:200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="emulating_variable_width">
   <form id="srxForm" method="post">
         <div id="qsrxSearchbar">            
             <div id="scope"> Person Name </div>
             <input type="text" id="theq" title="Search">
             <button id="btnSearch" type="button">Search</button>
          </div>
    </form>    
</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/v7YTT/1/

Comment: Hmm, this isn't what i really need, i would like to have the Input Field fill all available remaining yellow width, even if it has no focus

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
#emulating_variable_width{
    width:500px;

    height:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
}

input {
    width:320px;
    /*width:100%;*/
    float:left;
    font-size: 17px;
}
#scope{float:left;}
button{float:left;}
```

Comment: The point was to do something flexible, a fixed width won't work as the space won't be always 500px and label can change dynamically