# Section element shrinking due to overflow:auto?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 section in my HTML document see **[Here](http://codeandcode.co/wrapping-bug/wrapping-bug.html)**, now when i reduce the window size to about 820px the 2ns section shrinks , Why does that happen?

see screenshot below:

[image: browser bug]

now the second section has `overflow:auto`, if I remove that, everything works fine, **[Link HERE](http://codeandcode.co/wrapping-bug/wrapping-bug.html)**

But what is really causing the issue, the `section` element is definitely a block element, so why is it not taking 100% width? Can anybody explain?

Comment: You never specified section `width: 100%`, if you do it will work.

Comment: @NenadVracar , i would like to know why this is happening though ! `WHY` is really important to me .

Comment: It has to do something with your top section. If you delete your top section it will get `width: 100%`

Comment: @NenadVracar yup , i've noticed that ! :0

Comment: Its width of that left part

Comment: Its `float: left` on `intro-wrpr` so if you add `overflow: hidden` on `intro-lpoo` it will fix it. I think the problem is you didn't clear floats properly.

Comment: where have i not cleared floats properly ! ?

Comment: do u even realise this is not a problem with floats , but `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: Ok, well i am sure you will figure it out.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik  Do you know what clearfix does, or you use it without understanding? And your second link is the same link.

Comment: @CroaToa if you genuinly feel its a clearfix bug , state it . i feel its not . I have a reasonable understanding of it !

Answer (score 0):

You should delete `section` element's `margin-top: -1px;` style or set `.intro-lpoo` element's style: `overflow: auto`. The reason what I thought is here: [BFC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Your floating elements on the top section cause the issue. If you use clearfixes , you will not have any problems!Also use the following property for responsive images.

```
img{
 max-width:100%;
 height:auto;
}
```

Comment: @NascoChachev , i want to know why the problem is happening.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik , you've set max-width:66% to your container. that's the first problem. You'r telling that u want the 100% width but in the same time , you are setting max-width property with 66%... , you are also using floating elements. Instead of setting overflow:auto , you can use clearfixes , much better. Sometimes when you float something , it totally ruins everything on the page , exactly like right now.

Comment: @nNasco , nope . 66% width is applied on the child of the sectio , not the section itself.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Jesus man , that happens because of the floating elements on the top section bro.. that float property ruins your things... just use clearfix... add clear:both to the 2nd section man!!!!! ....

Comment: i have used clerfixes ! :)

Comment: see how overflow:auto functions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244927/input-text-auto-width-filling-100-with-other-elements-floating   , i think thats the issue , but want to know why , check the answer ! this has nothing to do with floats and clearfixs . check the answer .

Answer (score -1):

Ok, let's think about it.
You have `intro-lpoo` section with `height: 100%` and 2 divs into it with `float`. And 1 of this divs have `height: 0` because in that you place absolute positioned `img`. The reason why your `why-coworking` not shrinks  from the very beginning is `height: 100%` of `intro-lpoo`. But when you make your browser resolution smaller - `height: 100%` of `intro-lpoo` getting smaller, and because your right div (which contain absolute positioned img) have `height: 0` and your left div ( `intro-wrpr` ) have `float: left` thats why `why-coworking` shrinks and fills available space next to `intro-wrpr`.

I hope to able to explain

Comment: Why do u think i've used clearfix ? the bug is with the behavior of `overflow:auto` .

Comment: Your clearfix doesnt work. because there is nothing in your right div (absolute positioned img is out from page, think that). You can verify this, just remove `float: left` from `lpoo-info-graphic` and test it. Thanks for downvote)

Comment: see here http://i.imgur.com/FWzwSDv.jpg , i have removed the absoluting positiong for the image , which means the height `lpoo-info-graphic` is no longer zero , also tried with absolute positioning  the image , both ways does't make a difference . also the image proves , the width of the 1st section is 100% !