# Borders disappear in Chrome when I zoom in

Tags: html, css, border, zooming

I have this really simple form: http://jsfiddle.net/TKb6M/91/. Sometimes, when I zoom in or out using Chrome, the input borders disappear. For example, when I zoom to 90% I get:

[image]

Naturally, your mileage may vary.

In case you're wondering about those `<span>` tags, I added them following the recommendation at [How do I make an input element occupy all remaining horizontal space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189608/how-do-i-make-an-input-element-occupy-all-remaining-horizontal-space/7190310#7190310).

Is there a problem with my CSS or is this a Chrome bug? It seems to work fine on Firefox. What can I do to avoid this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: I've also seen 1px of padding being removed on zoom level 90%. It was a padding rule on a `<table>` element.

Comment: I've also noticed that if your border is style "double" then one of the "double" lines may disappear.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Luís Pureza has solved his issue, but I found a really easy way to solve it changing only this:

If you have a table border like this one:

```
INPUT,TEXTAREA {
border-top: 1px solid #aaa
}
```

Change it to this one:

```
INPUT,TEXTAREA {
border-top: thin solid #aaa
}
```

I found this solution across this link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/r1neUxqo5Gc

I hope it helps

Comment: Much better and more consistent solution

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now. It worked better than I expected. Huge thank you

Comment: `thin` doesn't work!!! no difference from `1px` !

Comment: didn't work for me either

Answer (score 34):

You are forcing Chrome to do  subpixel calculation, and this usually has strange behaviours.

If you change the height of the input to 30px, then a 90% zoom works ok (because this is 27px), but a zoom of 75% not (because this is 22.50 px).

You can also avoid this by giving the border a width of 3px. In this case, you will see that the borders width is different in different places .

Anyway, the very best solution is to give more space around the inputs so that the border can be drawn cleanly even if it is in a subpixel position.

Comment: I had a similar problem, the border on the right side of the button was gone when zooming in/out. Adding the padding around the button fixed the border for me. Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't it just round up to the nearest pixel?

Comment: Hi @ESR, I want to implement this, but in my case I have dropdown which has 10 vals and after 5 I am using overflow: auto. In this case I am not sure how can I give more padding at bottom. Only bottom border is disappearing in my case.

Answer (score 9):

I know I'm late in the game, but fudging it a bit and set the border width to 1.5px seems to do the trick every time.

Comment: My problem was the opposite. Borders disappeared on bootstrap boxes when I zoomed OUT. This solution fixed it.

Comment: In my case, 1px doesn't disappear on Firefox, bit does it in Chrome. With 1.5px the behavior is right in Chrome, but Firefox shows 2px width...

Comment: In my case borders on Chrome disappeared on 100% zoom and appeared while zooming out or zooming in

Comment: Whatever you do with `border-width` just shifts the problem to other lines in your table. Any value that you give it may fix it on that one line, but creates the issue on other lines. I showed this in my thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71789886/chome-border-thickness-issue-on-zoomed-resolutions-border-width-px-does-not And no, there's nothing "magic" about 1.5, it doesn't fully work either.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with a bordered `div` wrapping borderless `input` , and all the great answers here does not helped me.

Finally, adding:

```
overflow: auto;
```

to the `div` element (the one with the problematic border) did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your setting a fixed height, and when zooming the input is growing larger than that height, making the border disappear. Use line-height and padding to get the desired height instead - see [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/henrikandersson/kBmvA/)

**Update:** Ignore what I said, it's because you're setting `overflow:hidden` on your span, removing that should do the trick. Might result in a need to change width of input though.

On a side note; you're making your span a block element which is fine and works, but it looks a bit bad. Try using block elements, like a  instead of changing an inline element to a block, if possible.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem seems to persist.

Comment: The `overflow:hidden` bit is necessary to allow the input's width to go up to `100%`, which is something I'd like to keep.

Comment: For me the set `height: 32px` made the border disappear. I got the desired height of the `<select>` element set `padding: 0.2rem` on it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with chrome in 2018 - the top border was missing on inputs and textareas. The fix was to specify the top border in css simply as

```
INPUT,TEXTAREA {
border-top: 1px solid #aaa
}
```

I can't explain why that was needed, and it was only losing the borders in certain places, but at least that was a quick workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In case overflow: hidden is neccessary , mention overflow: hidden only for the browser you are facing the width issue . In other browser, metion display: flex so that the width is automatically taken correct and also, so that on zooming in/out the borders do not disappear.

For example :
Width was not correct in my case only for IE, so I mentioned :

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
.spanStyles {
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
}
}
```

And the zooming in/out issue was occuring in firefox and chrome, so I mentioned

```
.spanStyles {
 display : flex;
}
```

this resolved my issue in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your answers above, I got the border issue such as this[image: click to look at the image], the border display is a mess when zoomed down. finally found `overflow: hidden` worked for me.

```
export const InputWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  padding: 16px 0 16px 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue for textarea and adding following line of styling to textarea worked for me.

```
border: "1px solid #ccc"
```