# How to stop browser resizing 1px wide image to 0px

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to insert an vertical image 1 pixel wide into my webpage but depending on the browser, zoom level or position of other elements on the page the image is often resized to be 0 pixels and dissapears. How can I stop this? Am I doing this wrong?

My html image (green space is just 1 pixel of green.

```
 <IMG class="dividerImage dday3" SRC="/SafeSiteLive/images/safesite_documents/icons/greenspace.gif">
```

My css

```
.dividerImage {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 1px;
}
```

Some green vertical images not displaying
[image: Some green vertical images not displaying]

Different zoom level more of the images display
[image: Different zoom level more of the images display]

Comment: seems weird you are not using a border or bg of an element. But check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547580/borders-disappear-in-chrome-when-i-zoom-in

Comment: I think that what people are going to tell you is that there's no reason to use an image to draw a border. Use `border`.

Comment: May be she/he has a reason for using an image instead of border and may be she/he is willing to enlighten us... :)

Comment: Because I don't want the border to be the full length of the div. Should I use a empty div for these instead?

Ok yes should have used a border instead works much better thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have been using an empty div instead, works much better.

```
 <div class="dividingDiv"> 
     &nbsp;
 </div>
```

And the css.

```
.dividingDiv {
    border-left: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
    height: 50vh;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 0;
}
```

Comment: No you shouldn't and this is the anti-web. Not able to help with any other solution without knowing the structure of the page.