# 1px border is rounded to 0px while zoomed out

Tags: html, css, safari, pixel

I have a button that has the following CSS code:

```
.btn--border, .popup input[type=submit] {
  border: 1px solid #d7ccbf !important;
  background: 0 0;
  color: #b07f46;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: .625rem;
}
```

It works fine everywhere, except Safari. When a user zooms out, one of the borders is lost in Safari:

[image]

I assume, it has something to do with the rounding. Is there a solution?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2aj3rhxs/4/)

Comment: I'm not sure i don't have safari to check also. try like this  border:solid solid #d7ccbf !important;
    border-width:1px 1px 1px 1px 1px;

Comment: If your issue only occurs when you zoom out [this might be your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547580/borders-disappear-in-chrome-when-i-zoom-in). I however do not experience what you're describing in safari 9.0