# Why doesn't css border-bottom show in these inline divs when applying a fractional height?(Only Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, border, overlap

So I have this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ionescho/4d07k799/4/

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
<div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div><div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  line-height:0;
  width:100%;
}
.row{
  height:100px;  /* <--- try putting 100.66px here or some other fractional pixel value*/
  width:100.232323px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:red;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
  border-right:1px solid black;
  line-height:0;
}
```

IF I apply a height of 100px to the class .row, I can see the border-bottom. If I apply a non-integer value to height( ex: 100.66px ), it disappears.
Other times ( ex height: 100.22px ) it shows.

Is there a way to fix this? 
If for example I have a height expressed in percentage, it may resolve to a non-integer pixel height and then I will not see the border-bottom.

UPDATE: this happens only on CHROME!

Comment: Check your jsfiddle and it's working proper

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it only happens on Chrome. Try putting 100.66px at .row height

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14242055/4334348

Comment: Also working on chrome. Which version you are using? And don't use value in decimal .https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units

Comment: Check how decimal px working. http://www.paulund.co.uk/decimal-places-in-width-using-pixels

Comment: @ketan Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)

Comment: I am checking in latest 50.0.2645.4(64-bit) and it's working.

Comment: Try to zoom in and out, the border is present

Comment: I know it's present in the DOM but the issue is that it is not visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `float: left;` in place of `display:inline-block;`. It will work for any height.

Answer (score 1):

Browser can't render half pixel so it is doing approximation and your divs are collapsing eachother. If for some reason you need this height (?) you can compensate it by adding:

```
margin-bottom: .66px;
```

[sample](https://jsfiddle.net/mf36kdag/)

side note - on hidpi screens (aka retina) your example with fractions is looking good. This is because each pixel in css has more than one pixel on display [MDN devicePixelRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio)

Answer (score 0):

Abhinav give a good way.But you can do it by increasing `border-bottom` with respected `height`.You can check this in **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/q6m81knq/1/)**

Comment: Yeah.. but this has a nasty side-effect of doubling the visible bottom-border of the lowest elements.

Comment: to avoid this you can use `margin-bottom` .I appreciate abhinav answer.My answer is optional way.Thanks :)