# <hr> tags render with different height

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with some `<hr>` tags on my website.
 
[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RouzD.png)

As you can see in this very simple fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bau1hp9L/ the `<hr>` tags do not all render in the same height.
the CSS  for the `<hr>` is very simple, so no interference from other stuff...

```
hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #243588;
}
```

any ideas on why this is happening?

I want all the `<hr>`'s to have 1px height.

Some more information:

It is not always the same item that is shown bigger if i tweak the css inside the browser. e.g. I set height to 1px then to 0.5px then back etc.. - it now is a different `<hr>` tag that is displayed thicker (cant reproduce in jsfiddle unfortunately)

If I set the `<hr>`'s to `height: 0.5px`, now the `<hr>` that was too big is rendered with 1px height - as desired, but one of the other `<hr>`'s disappears randomly.

If i set `height: 0.05em` i get the desired 1px height for all of the `<hr>`'s but it seems a bit hacky to me...
I dont really want to scale height depending on the font-size of the parent div. I want it to be 1px in height.

EDIT: Please try to resize your JSFiddle preview window vertically - you will then eventually experience this behaviour too.

Any guesses?

Comment: I don't see any problem with `<hr>`, all of it has `1px` height.

Comment: They are all showing up as 1 px for me too.

Comment: I`m using Firefox, and Im having the same problem when using Chrome too...
Seems like this is some kind of weird display bug depending on screen size maybe?

Comment: Please try to resize your JSFiddle preview window vertically - you will then eventually experience this behaviour too...

Comment: I think this is screen rendering thing. As screen's display is based on pixels, So if you give `0.5px` that will behave weird. Better you give `height: 1px` and keep the zoom level of browser to 100%.

Comment: @OMPRAKASH this is exactly what I have in my CSS.
Try to resize the JSFiddle Window vertically. Maybe you will experience the same behaviour.

Comment: I have seen, what you're trying to say. But, i don't think it's an issue or a bug. it's just screen render thing.

Comment: @OMPRAKASH I dont seem to get why the screen can`t render 1px as 1px...
The only solution I now found is to set height to 0.05em -.- for me still weird behaviour but ok. btw i dont understand why my question is downvoted...

Comment: With that also your problem remains @DigitalJedi, try to zoom in or zoom out.

Comment: @OMPRAKASH I`m no talking about zooming. I dont care about the weird behaviour when zooming. I want it to look fine on 100%. When Im on 100% and having height: 0.05em i dont experience different hr sizes. Also not when resizing the jsfiddle window vertically. Closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try switching to "thin" instead of specifying a pixel height:

```
hr {
  border-top: thin solid #243588;
}
```

That fixes it for me, at all zoom levels. (Only tested in Chrome and Opera, so far, though.) It also feels more descriptive: I don't care how many pixels it is, I simply always want it to look like a thin line.

Found [(in context of input boxes) here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50912523/841830) and they got it from https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/r1neUxqo5Gc (appears it was a bug/feature introduced in Chrome 62, about 2 years ago).

Comment: This is actually pretty helpful and and gives the line (typically) 1px. Atleast all the lines look the same when doing this. thx for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are zoom-scaling your webbrowser, and the 1px height sometimes gets scaled unevenly, i.e. on a 150% zoom, some of the pixels of your page will be duplicated, and some won't.

Reset your view zoom scale to 100%.

Comment: You are right, zoom scaling is changing the different height. Im on 100% tho, and still experiencing this issue. When on 90% everything is fine haha

Answer (score 0):

There will be problem with your  tag, I change the code please check it -

```
 <head>
 </head>
 <div class="container">
 <hr>
   <section>
       Hallo
    </section>
  <hr>
    <section>
       Hallo2
    </section>
 <hr>
    <section>
       Hallo3
    </section>
</div>
```

Basically problem with font size.

Comment: I see you removed the <h1> tag in the first section. This does not change anything for me. Still. setting the height to 0.05em on 100% zoom factor in my browser changes all the <hr>'s to 1px, no matter how i resize the jsfiddle preview! - its hacky but it solves my issue