# Why are my some element borders fainter than others?

Tags: html, css

I need to have same height for `title-subline` element but the 2nd one is a bit smaller.

I really do not know why this happens (maybe they have same size on your screen because it's ok on my monitor but not on my laptop).

Html output image:

[image: html output]

```css
.title-subline {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.title-subline::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: inherit;
  width: 70px;
  background: #0C6638;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-subline"></div>
<div class="title-subline"></div>
<div class="title-subline"></div>
```

Comment: They appear identical to me. Does the snippet show the problem?

Comment: Do you mean that it appears fainter than the first and third in the image? This is likely due to sub-pixel rounding when the display is scaled.

Comment: I suspect this is a side-effect of having to align CSS pixels to the display's physical pixel grid. At some display resolutions the line is going to land where you'd need a half-pixel in each direction to get a 2-pixel line. The display can't do half-pixels so there are tradeoffs.

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547580/borders-disappear-in-chrome-when-i-zoom-in

Comment: @isherwood. Yes, the second one is fainter. not just the second one => 2, 4, 6 , ... if I add

Comment: Ok. There's a lot to be found on SO about that already. Good luck.

Comment: For me, with Firefox the 2nd line is smaller, with Edge it appears fainter (the size is ok) on a ~21" screen.