# button with display:block not stretched

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style>
        button {
            display: block;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid black">
        <button>hello</button>
        <button>hi</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is why buttons don't stretch to 100% width if their `display` is `block`. How to achieve this? I can't set style of buttons to `width: 100%` because they would overflow their parent block because of the margin.

Comment: have you added position:relative; and then added width:100% ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [input with display:block is not a block, why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030793/input-with-displayblock-is-not-a-block-why-not)

Comment: Qtax: `box-sizing: border-box` hasn't worked for me. Don't know why.

Comment: EvilP: `position: relative` does nothing here.

Comment: I realise the above is just an example, but you have an error in your DOCTYPE declaration.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584890/why-does-displayblock-not-stretch-buttons-or-input-elements and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567988/what-is-it-in-the-css-dom-that-prevents-an-input-box-with-display-block-from-ex

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The initial defination of **Button Layout** was committed on 2019, which solved the rendering problem of button elements. https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/4143.

we could refer to the [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#button-layout) to see an important rule of Button Layout as follows:

> If the computed value of 'inline-size' is 'auto', then the used value is the **fit-content inline size**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size

we should know that a block with `inline-size:fit-content | max-content | min-content` will shrink its width even if `display:block`.(by the way, `width:fit-content | max-content | min-content` does the same effect)

try this (require chrome 57+, but in FireFox 66+ we could try with `inline-size:max-content`):

```
<div style="
  inline-size: fit-content;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #ddd, #fff);
  padding: 2px 6px;
  border: 0.5px solid #bbb;
  font-size: 13px;"
>click me!</div>
```

[view result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StHx2.png)

Comment: This should be the selected answer!

Comment: According to the Chrome devtools, the computed value of a vexing button's `inline-size` is that of its width, not `auto`. So why the quoted rule is still applied here?

Comment: It wasn't super clear from this answer, but the solution for me was `inline-size: 100%`

Answer (score 10):

You can add padding to `div` container, and remove horizontal margin from buttons. Then you can apply width 100% to them:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style>
        button {
            display: block;
            width:100%;
            margin: 10px 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid black; padding:0 10px;">
        <button>hello</button>
        <button>hi</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xwt9T/1/

Comment: I would suggest using box-sizing: border-box, to keep button padding inside that 100%

Comment: This is just a workaround. The correct answer to the question "why buttons don't stretch to 100% width" is the one from 彼術向 bellow this.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this ,

```
<div style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid black">
    <button style="width:100%; float: left;margin-left:0px;">hello</button>
    <button>hi</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

`flex-grow: 1` will produce the expected behavior.

Comment: @SephReed I cannot reproduce OPs behavior now, button always stretches for me (Firefox, Chrome, IE11). What's your setup?

Comment: Brave, so same thing.  Inversely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57154038/can-i-make-a-div-shrink-to-text-width-like-a-button