# Why doesn't "display: block" & "width: auto" stretch a button to fill the container?

Tags: html, css

When I set `display: block;` and `width: auto;` on a button, I'd expect the button to stretch to fill the container as other block elements do. For some reason, it doesn't, at least not in latest Chrome.

When Googling around, I found a lot of people asking the same question, who were satisfied with an answer to *"How do I stretch my buttons to fill the container?"* That is **not** what I'm interested in. (I'm perfectly able to stretch my buttons any way I need.) Inspecting button properties, including the ones imposed by default by the browser didn't help me either.

**I'd like to understand, what causes buttons to ignore `display: block; width: auto;` and stay horizontally sized based on their contents.**

---

Here's a demonstration of what I mean:

```css
button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button style="width: auto;">button with `display:block; width:auto;`</button>
<button style="width: 100%;">button with `display:block; width:100%`</button>
```

I'd expect the button with `width:auto;` to be stretched as well.

---

*Just to be absolutely clear, the above is not a duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030793/input-with-displayblock-is-not-a-block-why-not) or any similar questions that only have answers describing the ways to stretch the elements in question.*

*The above is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567988/what-is-it-in-the-css-dom-that-prevents-an-input-box-with-display-block-from-ex) either. Though the **answer** applies here as well, because apparently the issues with sizing of input and buttons have the same core cause, the **question** doesn't mention buttons at all. Furthermore, there seems to be some uncertainty on whether `<button>` is even a proper "replaced element". This post (arguably) well serves the purpose of leading users with an issue to its solution.*

Answer (score 40, accepted):

*(Shameless copy of the answer at this [source and possible dublicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567988/what-is-it-in-the-css-dom-that-prevents-an-input-box-with-display-block-from-ex), which extracted the information from [this article](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements).)*

> There are a few elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, `<button>`, `<img>`,
>   `<object>`, and `<textarea>`) that are considered replaced elements
>   whose appearance and dimensions are defined by an external resource.
>   (e.g. the operating system, a plugin, etc).
>
> > Replaced elements can have intrinsic dimensions—width and height
> >     values that are defined by the element itself, rather than by its
> >     surroundings in the document. For example, if an image element has a
> >     width set to auto, the width of the linked image file will be used.
> >     Intrinsic dimensions also define an intrinsic ratio that’s used to
> >     determine the computed dimensions of the element should only one
> >     dimension be specified. For example, if only the width is specified
> >     for an image element—at, say, 100px—and the actual image is 200 pixels
> >     wide and 100 pixels high, the height of the element will be scaled by
> >     the same amount, to 50px.
> >
> > Replaced elements can also have visual formatting requirements imposed
> >     by the element, outside of the control of CSS; for example, the user
> >     interface controls rendered for form elements.

With HTML5 you have a couple more of those like `<audio>` and `<canvas>` and [some more](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#replaced-elements).

Please note that - as you will see in the discussions in the comments - `button` is not really a [replaced element defined by w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html). However it is behaving like one, which is discussed further in [this article](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/15/formal-weirdness/).

Comment: Great, thanks. It looks like my question is pretty much a duplicate of the one you linked. As I haven't been able to actually find that one when looking for it, I'll my question open.

Comment: The problem is that `<button>` is not and has never been a replaced element. It can't be, since unlike the other elements on the list, its content tree is fully rendered

Comment: @Alohci replaced elements are elements that get their style from outside of the stylesheet. All form elements have a default style, set by the browser. That includes `button`.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not talking about its style, I'm talking about its *contents*. It's an element's contents that are *replaced*. See http://jsfiddle.net/w50u3kc5/ to see how a button's contents are not replaced.

Comment: @Alohci I'm happy to be taught otherwise. Do you mind pointing me to the w3c specification of "replaced elements" and how `button` isn't one?

Comment: Sure. First of all, understand that "replaced elements" is a CSS concept. [CSS 2.1 Section 3.1 Definitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/conform.html#replaced-element) describes it, though not as clearly as one would like. It starts of though by saying "An element whose *content* is outside the scope of the CSS formatting model ...". A button's content is definitely subject to the CSS formatting model, as per my earlier jsfiddle.

Comment: I see, you might be right. [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html) is the w3c definition. [Sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements) specifically mentions buttons though. [This article](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/15/formal-weirdness/) on the other hand discusses that `button` isn't a replaced element, but strangely behaves like one. You're right, I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: Historically speaking, the whole freaking point of the button tag was to give us something that wasn't a replaced form input of `type="button"` we could use that gave us complete styling control. Treating it as a replaced element forces us to go back to semantically misusing A tags or divs in scenarios where we need that level of control

Comment: Still about a hundred times better than input type=button. :)