# How to center a button WITHOUT a div using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a button **without** a div. The button is as follows

```
<body>
  <button>Some Text</button>
</body>
```

I have tried using a few different techniques such as:

```
text-align: center
```

and

```
margin:0 auto;
```

but these don't work.

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` will work if you have a set width on the button

Comment: Could we know why you want it centered "WITHOUT" a div ?

Comment: @Aaron, you can align center without set width

Comment: `text-align: center` works also if you add it to your `body {text-align: center;}`

Comment: I want to center the button without a div because having a button inside of a div just to center the button seems like a waste of a div.

Comment: There is no such thing as a waste of a div.. You can use it to make your code look more refined and structured.

Comment: Superfluous divs are a waste. @kamal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its simple, just make it display as a block element:

```
<body>
  <button>Some Text</button>
</body>

button {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/df216mho/

Comment: This behaviour is really counterintuitive

Comment: I expect a `display: block` element to use the full width of its container

Comment: Exactly, you are telling the button to use the full width of its container, body in this case, and get auto margins.

Comment: Can you explain why this works for a `<button>` where as a `<div>` will need it's width set?

Comment: I'm saying that this behaviour is specific to the `button` element. If you try this with a `div` (again without specifying its width), you will see it would take the whole width

Comment: I'm assuming the `<button>` element must auto calculate and set it's own width for this to happen.

Comment: Ok. I found this interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605390/why-doesnt-display-block-width-auto-stretch-a-button-to-fill-the-contai

Comment: @Brewal that seems to confirm my assumption that they are calculated for the element.

Comment: Yes. Anyway @taxicala, IMO, this should be mentionned in this answer because of the specificity.

Answer (score 4):

Try this (You dont need a extra div or set a width)

**CSS**

```
button{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/53Lgo94v/3/)**

Comment: No need for the `display` property here, incidentally.

Answer (score 1):

Use this. It works:

```
<body>
  <button style="position: relative; left: 50%;" >Some Text</button>
</body>
```

I used inline CSS since its easier to show on here.

Comment: This is close, but not 100%. This solution does not take into account the width of the button. This will move the left edge of the button to the center rather than the center of the button to the center.

Comment: if the button is wide enough, it will not be centered, only the pivot point of the button will start at the center.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a set width then `margin: 0 auto;` will work.

```css
button {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The reason you do not need to set a width for a `<button>` with `margin: 0 auto;` when you also set it to `display: block;` is that a `<button>` is a replaced element. Basically they are elements that have a predetermined width and height without the use of CSS.

Checkout this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605390/why-doesnt-display-block-width-auto-stretch-a-button-to-fill-the-contai) provided by **@Brewal** for a few more details.

Comment: What happens if the text of the button is wider than the button itself? this wont work

Comment: So, depending on the text of the button, you will have to adjust the width of it? or create extra classes for each button depending on the width?