# Centering the link as the button

Tags: css

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #103d82;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d2cfcd;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center; 
}

div .button {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="button">Link</a>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

My two elements have the same CSS, however button is centered and not my link.
How to do the width of the link is calculated in the same way as the button?
Is it possible without added properties to the container?

Thanks

Comment: No, in this case my button is not centered because margin 0 auto doesn't work with inline-block.

Comment: Yes you are right, the width of my link is 100% and not my button. The width of the button is calculated by the browser.

Comment: The `button` element behaves like a *replaced element* - which are elements whose appearance and dimensions are defined by an external resource. So although the `button` has a computed `display` property value of `block` it does not occupy the full available width of the containing parent element since its `width` property is already computed as well. For more information, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605390/why-doesnt-display-block-width-auto-stretch-a-button-to-fill-the-contai

Answer (score 4):

You can add max-width/width properties and `box-sizing:border-box` to make them behave the same :

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #103d82;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d2cfcd;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="button">Link</a>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

You can also try `fit-content` value of width. Simply pay attention to browser support: https://caniuse.com/#search=fit-content

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #103d82;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d2cfcd;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="button">Link</a>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Another idea is to change the `display:block` to `display:table` and both links and buttons will behave the same :

```css
.button {
  display: table;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #103d82;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d2cfcd;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="button">Link</a>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @StevenMouret not too robust, you mean what ? :)

Comment: @StevenMouret i added another solution ;)

Comment: You know the OP is in good hands when Mr Afif is on the scene :) For the record, it may be worth considering to mention that `keyword` `width` values, like `fit-content`, are currently under the specification status of "Working Draft", and considered an *experimental API* recommended not to be used in production. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#fit-content **&** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Specifications **as well as** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError yes i totaly agree :) that's why i added the "caniuse" link but i will elaborate more with your links ;)

Comment: I overlooked that link for some reason :/

Comment: Can't miss it now :)

Comment: Robust is not the good word. Your solution require to give a default width. But I think I will do that. Thanks guys.

Comment: @StevenMouret i updated my answer with another way if you are still interested :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to change `display: block` to `display: inline-block` instead
then add `text-align: center` to their parents instead of `margin: 0 auto` as follow:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #103d82;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d2cfcd;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center; 
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="button">Link</a>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but in your case you add property to the parent. Button does not need specificity on its parent.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
   width: 100px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.button {
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #103d82;
   background: #fff;
   border: 1px solid #d2cfcd;
   font-size: 1.4rem;
   text-align: center; 
   padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="button">Link</a>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```