# Can I make a div shrink to text-width like a button?

Tags: css

Buttons have a magic property where you can use `margin: auto` on them without setting a width.  I'd like to be able to do this with a div.  Is it possible?

```css
div, button {
background-color: #FFA;
display: block;
margin: auto
}
```

```html
<div> Center me </div>

<button> I Center Magically </button>
```

They do this by having a sort of magic internal sizing function which makes them only as big as their text:

[Why doesn't "display: block" & "width: auto" stretch a button to fill the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605390/why-doesnt-display-block-width-auto-stretch-a-button-to-fill-the-contai)

I would like to know if I can make a div do this, without wrapping it in any containers (I know flex box around it would work).

**Can I make a div shrink to text-width like a button, while still being display block, without necessitating a specific container?**

EDIT: `inline-block` will not work for my use case.

Comment: I think you are looking for 'inline-block' instead of 'block'

Comment: I am not.  Run the code snippet.  It specifically specifies display block.  As does the question.

Comment: You need to clear up your question. What are you trying to accomplish? You ask to make the div do what the button does, then you ask to make the button do what the div does.

Comment: Run the snippet.  I'm trying to make a div text-width, without using containers.  Notice how large the div is, and the button is not.  And yet they use the same styling.  This is because buttons have a magic text-width styling.  I want to know if it's possible to get that for a div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set a [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) on the `<div>` of [`fit-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#fit-content):

```css
div,
button {
  background-color: #FFA;
  display: block;
  margin: auto
}

div {
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>Center me</div>
<button>I Center Magically</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:table` and you will have better support than `fit-content` *(it doesn't work on Firefox, Edge and IE)*

```css
div,
button {
  background-color: #FFA;
  display: table;
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<div> Center me </div>

<button> I Center Magically </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

buttons will have `inline-size:fit-content` by default.

`width:fit-content` dose the same effect.

I have an answer on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60001153/11831252), where you can find spec ref.