# Make a <button> fill the whole width and (!) extend its container's size

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with `<button>` nodes that refuse to extend their container and, at the same time, fill the container. Update: The issue only appears in Firefox 42, not in Chrome 47.

```
<!-- This one has a limited width -->
<div class="outer">
  <!-- This one is positioned absolutely and shall be extended -->
  <div class="container btn1" style="top: 0px">
    <!-- These shall extend the container and fill the whole width -->
    <button>Some lengthy label for the button</button>
    <button>Another label</button>
    <button>Still another label</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Probably, this example demonstrated the issue best:
http://jsfiddle.net/5dh4j0hy/1/

I already found out that `<button>` is a "replaced element", which is the reason for my problems:

- [Why doesn't "display: block" & "width: auto" stretch a button to fill the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605390/why-doesnt-display-block-width-auto-stretch-a-button-to-fill-the-contai)
- [What is it in the CSS/DOM that prevents an input box with display: block from expanding to the size of its container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567988/what-is-it-in-the-css-dom-that-prevents-an-input-box-with-display-block-from-ex)

What I could not find out is: How do I solve my specific issue? As the fiddle demonstrates, `width: 100%` and `width: auto` do not achieve the desired result. And as this is no problem with borders or padding, `box-sizing: border-box` is not if relevance here, either.

Comment: I'm seeing the `width:100%` items being stretched across the full width of the container. Am I missing the issue? On Chrome 47

Comment: I'm seeing the same as @WillThresher on Chrome, Firefox 44, Edge 25.

Comment: It works for me too on Chrome 47, but doesn't work on Firefox 42 http://i.imgur.com/UnsXckX.png

Comment: Good point! I have observed the issue with Firefox 42 (only).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing on Firefox 42 (which seems to be the only browser currently exhibiting this issue), my suggestion is to use `min-width` rather than `width`.

So in your example, change this declaration block should work:

```
div.btn1 button { min-width: 100% }
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dh4j0hy/2/) to demonstrate. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Arg - I could have found this one. Works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Ah, well, I'm glad I was able to at least shorten your debugging process. =P