# Why Bootstrap btn needs width:100% to make bootstrap button go full width? shoudn't display:block; make button full width by default?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I can work this around, but I feel I don't understand something entirely. I'm used that whenever you apply `display:block;` to an element it will automatically go full width. However, when I apply `d-block` class to bootstrap 4 button (`.btn`) it does not go full width unless I add `width:100%;` css property or `.w-100` class.

I know that `.btn-block` class allows to make button full width, but this is not ideal, when you only want your button to be full width on certain breakpoint.

EDIT:

For those who asked for code:
https://codepen.io/samaxe/pen/LYERYxq

Comment: Please post your code. It's hard to know why without knowing what the button is contained in

Comment: There must be some other CSS which is causing this... `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">button with btn-block</button>` is full width using bootstrap-4

Comment: @Zim see edit, added code pen

Comment: I don't think this is a Bootstrap issue. This is how button (and input, select, etc...) behave as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567988/what-is-it-in-the-css-dom-that-prevents-an-input-box-with-display-block-from-ex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567988/what-is-it-in-the-css-dom-that-prevents-an-input-box-with-display-block-from-ex) buttons (like input, select, image, etc...) have intrinsic sizing from the element itself.

*But*, if you wanted to make the Button width responsive without using the grid columns, you can put it inside a flexbox container.

For example, here's 100% width on medium and down (auto width on lg and up)...

```
   <div class="p-5 d-flex">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary flex-grow-1 flex-lg-grow-0">button</button>
   </div>
```

[Codeply demo](https://codeply.com/p/ZTWQUXdWx2)