# Input tag exceeding the width of it's parent

Tags: html, css

Can someone explain why - in this instance - an input tag would exceed the width of it's parent? If you inspect the element it's got nothing to do with the padding, border or margins...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.foo {
  width: 400px;
}

.bar {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <input type="number" class="bar" />
</div>
```

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748575/default-input-element-size - it looks like the default input size is 20 characters. If you want to override this, you could override the `size` attribute, or just set `width: 100%;`

Comment: Interesting, so is this applicable to an input of type number? According to mozilla the attribute is only applicable to email, password, tel, url and text input types.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't realize that. I guess the default size is still 20 and that's why it's expanding beyond its parent.