# Side by side subitem, grand child of flex container sticks out of area

Tags: css

My goal is to do a "row" with three columns.  The layout works but when I add a specific class (which doesn't have width) it makes the grandchild input stick out.

My html is:

```
    <div class="product-box" >
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-child">
    <input class="qty-box">     
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <button type="button" class="qty-add-sub">
      <span class="qty-add">+</span>    
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <button type="button" class="qty-add-sub">
      <span class="qty-minus">-</span>  
    </button>  
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

My css is:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 180px;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 1;
}

.product-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #c5c5c5;
  border-radius: 5px;

}

input.qty-box {
  border: 2px solid rgb(179, 179, 179);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 55px;
}

.qty-add {
  color:rgb(84, 0, 0);
  font-size: 30px;
}

.qty-minus {
  color:rgb(84, 0, 0);
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

The display appears like so:
[image]

Sandbox URL:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/html-css-forked-eu1680?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: min-width: 0 to input

Comment: The div with the class .flex-container is set at 180px width however the input is set to a particular size which is overflowing it. A possible solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748575/default-input-element-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've had a good look at this and there's a few thing to note:

Setting the width of the input box to 100% works but there's still an element that pokes out of the end, this is due to the box-sizing being content-box and not border-box. I've set the flex box so that the first child tries to grow and the buttons don't. I've also set a width for your buttons too. Example below

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  gap:0.125rem;
}

.flex-child {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.flex-child:first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.product-box {
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #c5c5c5;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input.qty-box {
  border: 2px solid rgb(179, 179, 179);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
}

.qty-add {
  color: rgb(84, 0, 0);
  font-size: 30px;
}

.qty-minus {
  color: rgb(84, 0, 0);
  font-size: 30px;
}

.qty-add-sub {
  width: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-box">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-child">
      <input class="qty-box" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child">
      <button type="button" class="qty-add-sub">
          <span class="qty-add">+</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child">
      <button type="button" class="qty-add-sub">
          <span class="qty-minus">-</span>
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The input default size is 20 characters, and there is not
enough space for that

[input w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp)

If you want to resize the input to less characters you can use

```
<input size="number">
```