# How can I set auto-width/length on text input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm getting the value of a Stripe transaction fee and displaying it via a disabled text field.

There is a large gap in the sentence due to the input text field

`This is the amount $3.50____________that needs to be paid.`

**What I need:** (Need to close the gap)

`This is the amount $3.50 that needs to be paid.`

**How can I change this code to use an auto width on the text field or change the code to use a `span` to grab the transaction fee value?**

This is the line I would like to change:

`<input size='5' id="p-charge" type="number" disabled>`

Codepen if needed: https://codepen.io/daugaard47/pen/JwLRvZ

```js
var Pgoal = document.querySelector('.p-goal');
var Ffixed = document.querySelector('#f-fixed');
var Fpercent = document.querySelector('#f-percent');
var Pcharge = document.querySelector('#p-charge');
var checkbox = document.querySelector('#gift-check');
var totalBox = document.querySelector('.total-box');

var totalDonation = $('.total-box > span');

function f(n) {
  return Number((+n).toFixed(10));
}

function calcPcharge(goal, fixed, percent) {
  return (goal + fixed) / (1 - percent) - (goal);
}

function update() {
  console.log('update')
  var charge = calcPcharge(
    f(Pgoal.value),
    f(Ffixed.value),
    f(Fpercent.value / 100)
  );

  Pcharge.value = (charge || 0).toFixed(2);
  
  var total = checkbox.checked ? f(Pgoal.value) + f(charge) : f(Pgoal.value);

  totalDonation.text(total.toFixed(2));
  
  document.querySelector("input[name='amount']").value = total;
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'), function() {
  this.addEventListener('input', update);
  this.addEventListener('change', update);
});

update();

checkbox.addEventListener('change', update);
```

```css
input[type="number"]:disabled {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: tomato
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Cost $<span class="total-box"><span></span></span></h2>

<span>$</span>
<input type="number" min="1.00" max="200000.00" step="0.01" value="60" id="other_amount" name="other_amount" class="p-goal">
<span>USD</span>

<input type="hidden" id="f-fixed" type="number" value="0.30">
<input type="hidden" id="f-percent" type="number" value="2.9">

<p>Gift transaction fee of $ <input size='5' id="p-charge" type="number" disabled> so we can get 100% of your payment?</p>

<input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="yes" id="gift-check" autocomplete="off">Yeah, Sure!


<p>Total Amount $<span class="total-box"><span></span></span></p>
```

Comment: you cannot with only CSS, you will need JS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [width:auto for <input> fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622086/widthauto-for-input-fields)

Comment: @Laif Unfortunately no. In that example it's using a fixed width to control the size of the field.

Comment: Why are you using an input for this? I would suggest using scripting to make this happen but it would be much easier to just use scripting to insert the value alone

Comment: Honestly,  because I'm not very good at JS. I'm displaying the transaction fees associated with Strip. You can see that here. https://codepen.io/daugaard47/pen/JwLRvZ

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392493/adjust-width-of-input-field-to-its-input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the links others were suggesting didn't help me figure out the dynamic / fluid width issue with the input field. BUT it did get me motivated to figure out how to get the value into a `span` element rather than using the input field.

Here was my solution:

HTML:

1. Removed this `<input id="p-charge"  type="number">`
2. Replace with this `<span id="p-charge"></span>`

JS:

1. Add this `var totalFee = $("#p-charge");`
2. Add this `totalFee.text((charge || 0).toFixed(2));`

```js
var Pgoal = document.querySelector(".p-goal");
var Ffixed = document.querySelector("#f-fixed");
var Fpercent = document.querySelector("#f-percent");
var Pcharge = document.querySelector("#p-charge");
var checkbox = document.querySelector("#gift-check");
var totalBox = document.querySelector(".total-box");
var totalFee = $("#p-charge");
var totalDonation = $(".total-box > span");

function f(n) {
  return Number((+n).toFixed(10));
}

function calcPcharge(goal, fixed, percent) {
  return (goal + fixed) / (1 - percent) - goal;
}

function update() {
  console.log("update");
  var charge = calcPcharge(
    f(Pgoal.value),
    f(Ffixed.value),
    f(Fpercent.value / 100)
  );

  Pcharge.value = (charge || 0).toFixed(2);

  var total = checkbox.checked ? f(Pgoal.value) + f(charge) : f(Pgoal.value);

  totalFee.text((charge || 0).toFixed(2));

  totalDonation.text(total.toFixed(2));

  document.querySelector("input[name='amount']").value = total;
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("input"), function() {
  this.addEventListener("input", update);
  this.addEventListener("change", update);
});

update();

checkbox.addEventListener("change", update);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Cost $<span class="total-box"><span></span></span>
</h2>

<span>$</span>
<input type="number" min="1.00" max="200000.00" step="0.01" value="60" id="other_amount" name="other_amount" class="p-goal">
<span>USD</span>

<input type="hidden" id="f-fixed" type="number" value="0.30">
<input type="hidden" id="f-percent" type="number" value="2.9">

<p>Gift transaction fee of $<span id="p-charge"></span> so we can get 100% of your payment?</p>
<!-- <p>Gift transaction fee of $ <input id="p-charge"  type="number"> so we can git 100% of your payment?</p> -->

<input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="yes" id="gift-check" autocomplete="off">Yeah, Sure!

<p>Total Amount $<span class="total-box"><span></span></span>
</p>
```

This works for my needs at the moment, but I consider this "Spaghetti Code" and really need to rework all of it to something a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to calculate a number of pixels based on the number of characters the person put into the input using the `.value` attribute. You can then use `.length`, to calculate the length then multiply it by 10px for example.

```
function myfunction() {

   var smallValue = document.getElementById("p-charge");
   var bigValue = smallValue.value;
   var something = bigValue.length;
   something = something*10;
   var somethingElse = something + "px";
   var spannyThing = document.getElementById("forgotwhatidthisisSoReplace");
   spannyThing.style.width = somethingElse;
   setTimeOut(myfunction, 100);
}
myfunction()
```

Comment: Would you be able to expand on this or point me to a tutorial that can show me how to do this?

Comment: let me check, be back in a few hours