# React: how to make an input only as wide as the amount of text provided?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Simple enough question:
**I am trying to create inputs that are as large as the text supplied to them.**

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/long-snowflake-6u13n?file=/src/Test.jsx

My design intention is to generate inputs dynamically and then allow the user to have styles specific to each input that visually help break up each sentence based on outside events. But before I can move forward, it's really important that my input container **is only** as large as the text within.

> why not use a textarea? -- I have data that is particular to each sentence that I want to create unique styles for.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach from plain HTML/CSS and a working snippet , hidding the value typed inside a `span` behind the `input` set in an `absolute` `position`. CSS can make both `span` and `input` matching the same lenght/width. Stretching/collapsing a parent (`label`) will finish the job.

***In the courtesy of @silvenon** you may also find a react sample below the snippet*

```js
var val = document.querySelector('#test');
let tpl = document.querySelector('#tpl');
let text = val.value;
 tpl.textContent= text;

val.addEventListener("input", function () {// onchange ...
  let text= val.value;
  //console.log(text);
  tpl.textContent= text;
  });
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 2em;
  min-height: 1.4em;
}

#tpl {
  white-space: pre;
  /* max-width : could be wised to set a maximum width and overflow:hidden; */
}

#test {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: top;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<label><span id="tpl"></span><input id='test' value="Some test to try" ></label>
```

In the courtesy of @silvenon, you may find a react sample of that code.

```
const SentenceInput = styled.input`
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* added styles */
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: top;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
`

const Label = styled.label`
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 2em;
  min-height: 1.4em;
`

const Template = styled.span`
  white-space: pre;
  /* max-width : could be wised to set a maximum width and overflow:hidden; */
`

const Sentence = ({ initialValue }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue)
  return (
    <Label>
      <Template>{value}</Template>
      <SentenceInput
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={(event) => {
          setValue(event.target.value)
        }}
      />
    </Label>
  )
}
```

Comment: It will be very easy for OP to translate this to React, but for the sake of completeness if you want to edit your answer: https://gist.github.com/silvenon/0df75af6abb572c646c722341dcf7356

Comment: @silvenon , it is very kind of you, hopefully one day i'll be familiar enough with react to do so . Be safe.

Comment: Np  I added one more edit to be reviewed, I accidentally wrote `StyledInput` instead of `SentenceInput` when declaring the component. In hindsight I could've just pointed out the mistake here instead of having someone else approve the edit. 

Comment: thanks to both of you! I actually ended up implementing a very different solution after poking around a lot of different resources. It's a lot more involved compared to what is here and uses editable divs which might not be suitable for most environments. So, I dont think I'll post the alternative solution, at least not yet. That said, you both provided really great solutions. :)

Answer (score 3):

The `<input>` `size` attribute can be used to set the width. It works in the same way as ch units e.g. `<input size="10">` has a width of `10ch`. As with `ch` units, it works perfectly with monospaced fonts but is only an approximation when it comes to proportionally-spaced fonts.

To get a more accurate measurement with proportionally-spaced fonts, you can use the `scrollWidth` property of the `<input>` element itself to calculate the width. The trick is to set the value to 'auto' first to capture the content width before setting the value. Set the input `padding` to zero if you want to fit the content exactly.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const data = [
  { sentence: "Hello world, how are you?" },
  { sentence: "Sometimes in rains in the summer." },
  {
    sentence:
      "Depending where you currently live, it my even rain in the winter."
  }
];

const SentenceInput = (props) => {
  const { value, onChange } = props;
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const input = inputRef.current;
    input.style.width = 'auto';
    input.style.width = `${input.scrollWidth}px`;
  });
  return <input ref={inputRef} type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />;
};

const Test = () => {
  const handleChange = () => {};

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(({ sentence }, i) => {
        return (
          <SentenceInput key={i} value={sentence} onChange={handleChange} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `ch` unit would work if the typeface was monospace, otherwise character width varies. I would approach this problem by rendering an inline element holding the same text, measuring it and hiding it instantly every time the input field value changes.

To do this it's best to create a separate component for rendering sentences, let's call it `Sentence`:

```
const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {value.map(({ sentence }, i) => {
        return (
          <Sentence
            initialValue={sentence}
            key={i}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

`Test` would pass the initial value, then `Sentence` will continue maintaining its own state:

```
const Sentence = ({ initialValue }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue)

  return (
    <SentenceInput
      type="text"
      value={value}
      onChange={(event) => {
        setValue(event.target.value)
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Next, I'd add a `span` element that will serve as a measurer element, where the text should be styled the same way as in input elements, so the measurements turn out accurate. In your example in Chrome that would mean setting the font size to `13.3333px`.

Now for the trickiest part, we need to combine `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect`; `useEffect` will make the measurer visible, then `useLayoutEffect` will measure it and hide it

This is the result:

```
const Sentence = ({ initialValue }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue)
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false)
  const [width, setWidth] = React.useState('auto')
  const measurer = React.useRef(null)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setVisible(true)
  }, [value])

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (visible) {
      const rect = measurer.current.getBoundingClientRect()
      setWidth(rect.width)
      setVisible(false)
    }
  }, [visible])

  return (
    <>
      <span
        ref={measurer}
        style={{ fontSize: '13.3333px' }}
      >
        {visible && value}
      </span>
      <SentenceInput
        type="text"
        value={value}
        style={{ width: width + 1 }}
        onChange={(event) => {
          setValue(event.target.value)
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

I added `1px` to the computed `width` because it seems to remove a small horizontal scroll in the input fields.

This is for you to tweak further the way you want, for example how it should behave when it reaches the viewport width.

Comment: I made a plain HTML/CSS/JS answer, you can use whatever you think useful to your answer . i'll delete mine later (mainly about the CSS part to set span/input to the same size) .

Comment: Why would you delete yours? It's a different, and clearly much more elegant approach. 

Comment: It does not have the react spirit way of coding  ;)