# Fit input HTML component to the size of its content

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to fit the `<input>` HTML component to the size of its "content"? It doesn't respond to `width: fit-content` CSS.

Comment: [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4622119/16234808)

Comment: nop, when you type inside an input you actually fill the value attribute ;)  take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64092841/react-how-to-make-an-input-only-as-wide-as-the-amount-of-text-provided/64094013#64094013 or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69150051/get-input-children-of-grid-to-grow-and-shrink-based-on-content/69154637#69154637 if its also about ellipsis at a certain point

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thanks yes, that helps. Seems that "input" element does not allow that inherently, which is unfortunate :(