# How can I make the width of the input and the value of the input have a proportional width, like contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is contenteditable ,The border will become wider or narrower with the input value。[image]

How to make the  's border grow or shrink width the changing of the input value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [width:auto for <input> fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622086/widthauto-for-input-fields)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```html
      <input
        type="text"
        oninput="this.style.width = this.value.length + 'ch' "
      />
```