# display: block not expanding input to fill parent's width

Tags: css

How do I get the input to expand to the full width of the parent div? For label it worked fine. The code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/7h8Zg/

What makes the label expand but not the input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [input with display:block is not a block, why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030793/input-with-displayblock-is-not-a-block-why-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the inputs to be the same size as the `submit` button, you should add `width:97%` to the `input` rule.

http://jsfiddle.net/7h8Zg/15/

Comment: That appears to work, but do you know why the input doesn't expand on it's own like the label did?

Comment: From what I can tell, the `li .input` is floated left and its width does not span the entire display...until you set a `width` on the `input` element.

Answer (score 3):

change the left padding to percent, and use the rest for width, like so:

```
padding:0 0 0 2%;width:98%;
```

Comment: That works, but is not pixel perfect. It is still 1px over because of the border. Sorry for being picky but I just don't understand why the label expands but the input doesn't.

Comment: right, I think you can get it pixel perfect by putting the border on the parent container, and removing it from the input

Answer (score -1):

Adding

```
width: 100%;
```

to the input class allows the input to expand to the full size of the parent div.

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/7h8Zg/5/

Comment: It's close but it doesn't fully work. It actually makes the width higher than 100% because of the padding and border.