# Display:Block as an input submit, is it possible?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to us a display:block for and input submit? or do I have to create an image for the submit button?

```
<div class="signin_btn">
<a title="Current Members Sign-In" class="l_helpl" href="/">SIGN-IN</a>
</div>
```

Comment: yes; you can give display:block to an  input submit button

Comment: Is this code related to the question?

Comment: @Kobi yes, it is. that's currently the display:block I want as an input submit button

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030793/input-with-displayblock-is-not-a-block-why-not may be that's you want

Answer (score 0):

You can even do this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
.button
{
   width: 100px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: Red;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
</style>
<div>

<a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk" class="button"></a>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a title="Current Members Sign-In" class="l_helpl" href="/">
<span class="signin_btn">
SIGN-IN
</span>
</a>
```

This should do the trick. And of course change your styling to suit the changes.

Comment: Whats with the neg feedback this is w3c compliant, and this is the most straight forward way of doing what needs to be done without making an image or using jquery.

Comment: never put block element inside an inline element. You can use SPAN instead DIV. a is an inline element

Comment: my bad I its late and I wasnt thinking

Answer (score -1):

I think it is stupid for a person having more than 500 reps to ask this question. Anyway here is how I would do it

```
<div class="signin_btn">
<a title="Current Members Sign-In" class="l_helpl" href="/" style="display:block;">SIGN-IN</a>
</div>
```

But please be remembered that it is a bad practice to have a block level element inside an inline element.

Comment: What would a person's rep have to do with their CSS knowledge?