# Make new lines in CSS in form for each label

Tags: html, css, forms

I have HTML code

```
<form id="answers">
blue
<input id="0" type="radio">
red
<input id="1" type="radio">
pink
<input id="2" type="radio">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and I want to have each element in the new line. I don't want to use stuff like `<br>`. In CSS file I tried do this: `display: block` but nothing's changed.

Comment: You should put the texts in `<label>` elements.

Comment: Of cource you're right. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
#answers input {display: block;}
```

this will make every input in its own line.
If you wish to have every input with its label together in a line you should do something like

```
<form id="answers">
    <label>blue <input id="0" type="radio"></label>
    <label>red <input id="1" type="radio"></label>
    <label>pink <input id="2" type="radio"></label>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

css:
    #answers label {display: block;}

http://jsfiddle.net/barakedry/y6p54vzg/

Comment: also keep in mind that numerical id is not valid and that you should have give radio buttons the same name attribute

Comment: Numerical IDs are valid as of HTML5.

Comment: You are right!, everyday you learn something...
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `box-sizing:border-box;`.

There's more information on this very topic in this thread: [input with display:block is not a block, why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030793/input-with-displayblock-is-not-a-block-why-not)