# Arrange two checkboxes in same table cell vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if possible to arrange two `checkbox` input fields vertically  in same `td` cell? Below is example, there both of input fields are next to each other.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>
           <input type="number" />
           <input type="checkbox" name="ck1" id="ck1">A
           <input type="checkbox" name="ck2" id="ck2">B
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make new lines in CSS in form for each label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392197/make-new-lines-in-css-in-form-for-each-label)

Comment: @showdev That's not remotely a duplicate of that

Comment: @showdev OP is asking about a `td` element, that question is about a form, and see the given answers there

Comment: @KobyDouek In my opinion, `<td>` vs `<form>` is irrelevant here. The essence of the question is about putting inputs on separate lines, for which solutions appear in that post. Incidentally, your solution can be found there, too.

Comment: @showdev OP there was asking about CSS, without using `<br>`, which is the obvious answer here

Comment: @KobyDouek Since there are many ways to achieve this, there is nothing "obvious" about any one particular method being "the answer". In my opinion, CSS is a more effective solution than `<br>`. If you don't agree, don't vote for the duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

How about using a simple `<br>` with using `text-align:right` on the `<td>`?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='text-align:right'>
      <input type="number">
      <input type="checkbox" name="ck1" id="ck1">A<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="ck2" id="ck2">B
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What if there is input text field as well? How that can be organized in that case? So there is input text and two checkbox in the same cell.

Comment: @espresso_coffee And you want each to be on a separate line?

Comment: input text on the left and check box fields on the right on top of each other.

Comment: Then place your input text, then the checkbox, then break with `<br>`, then the 2nd line: input text, checkbox, etc. etc.

Comment: I updated my question. You will see all 3 input fields on the same line. I want in this case two checkbox fields on top of each other. Input text would be on the left.