# Make HTML form elements 'display only' - non-interactive

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm working on a dynamic form builder, where the user can add different blocks of content to a page (buttons, text inputs, paragraphs of text, images etc), which they can later publish and it will be a simple HTML form they can use.

For the 'preview' section of this application (where they are adding different blocks of content and modifying the content and look of it), it occurs to me that the simplest way to do this, is to just display the end product HTML itself and that way I'm more or less guaranteed that what is displayed in the preview matches what is displayed in the actual form.

Where this is important is with obscure styling quirks, [such as the behaviour of buttons with display:block.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030793/input-with-displayblock-is-not-a-block-why-not)

However, I don't want the the preview to be actually interactive like the real form would. That is, I don't want the following behaviours:

- Inputs receiving focus and being able to insert content
- Buttons having click animations
- Clicking links navigating
- Default hover styles occuring.

Also, in terms of accessibility, it might be very confusing if there are a bunch of input that don't do anything appearing on the screen.

Is there a browser native/standard way to do this?

My fallback will likely be to disable all of the elements. But this won't work for links for example.

An alternative might be to put an invisible div on top of the form, which captures all of the click events. But I don't like this from an accessibility POV.

Is using the `role="presentation"` intended for this?

### Code Example

As an example here, see some sample code here: https://codepen.io/dwjohnston/pen/qBrGPmr?editors=1111

Now for this, I have the divs with `role="button"` - These buttons are intended to be clickable, - when you click them the side panel will show content configuration eg, the default value of the input, label, etc.

Already, there is a problem - interactive content is not permitted inside a button.

But also, I shouldn't be able to tab to those controls, (now I can manually add `tabindex = "-1"`, but that's not the complete picture). I don't want to confuse screen readers etc.

Comment: Why not just paint a transparent overlay on top of the preview, catching all the clicks and mouse events?

Comment: Hey, what extra info are you looking for in an answer so I can amend mine to give you the info you need?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Ha good question. I'm not sure, this bounty might have been a bit impulsive. Possibly just code examples to show how it behaves. I might update my question with some code samples of what I'm looking at.

Comment: @dwjohnston hehe fair enough. For clarity in your example the `<button>` element is meant to be "the end product" and the wrapper with `role="button"` is the editor interface? So you want to be able to nest that button inside the wrapper without it causing confusion?

Comment: And for the `<input>` I presume you want to make it so that you cannot click into that `<input>` (as that may cause an error or confusion with event bubbling etc.). So you want a way to display those items visually, stop them being interactive for everybody and also explain things to a screen reader user so they make sense? I presume you are locked into this pattern or something very similar as well (i.e. you want to work with what you have rather than a complete redesign!)

Comment: re: end product  and editor interface  - yes that's correct.

Comment: re: redesign - I mean... certainly that's something up for consideration. however, what I've got here makes sense as one way you would do this, in which case - how would you solve these accessibility requirements.

Comment: @dwjohnston added a new section to my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65402376/2702894) that should hopefully let you use your current methodology and still make it accessible. There are loads of comments in the final snippet but any questions just ask. If you need anything further let me know.

Comment: IN 2014, I worked for a while on an authoring tool for epub3 books. The project is far from complete and now abandoned as far as I know, but maybe you can find interesting stuff:
https://github.com/Access4all/EPUB
You might be interested in the quiz building part, which are basically editable forms as you describe. I was essentially relying on contenteditable attribute, and at that time it worked not so bad. I haven't retried since, but I'm pretty sure it still does.

Answer (score 6):

### INFO

There is an edit to this question that addresses the specific issues OP has with their current implementation. I have left this first part here as my original answer.

### I don't want the the preview to be actually interactive like the real form would.

Why? Having the form be interactive would be great for all users (taking into account that some functionality needs to not work fully in a preview).

Let people see what default hover styles look like, what clicking links would do (i.e. click the link and alert says "would navigate to xxx page") etc.

I understand not wanting to be able to navigate to new pages and submit the form (any "save" or "update" actions plus any "navigation" actions) but everything else I believe should be able to work in a preview.

### Also, in terms of accessibility, it might be very confusing if there are a bunch of input that don't do anything appearing on the screen.

It would be far more confusing if a preview appeared on screen but then I couldn't navigate to the buttons, links etc.

How would that behave for a screen reader user? i.e. would you hide all elements using `aria-hidden="true"` (in which case how would they test the page?).

### My fallback will likely be to disable all of the elements. But this won't work for links for example.

This is really one of the worst ways you could handle it, `disabled` inputs generally can't receive focus so keyboard users would suffer when testing.

Plus if some elements in the final production form are disabled until a certain field is filled in (for example) then how could a user test that in your end form?

Also if you intercept the navigation for a link without explaining why the link doesn't work that could also cause confusion. (and yet again could that link open in a new window in "preview" mode if you explain that to end users? Obviously depends if it is a static link etc. but just a thought on a way users can check any custom links point to the right place).

### Proposed Solution

I would say you need two versions of the finished form. The "real world" one and the "preview" one.

The HTML can be (read "should be") identical but you need to implement JavaScript handlers to disable the functionality you don't want to be active.

There is nothing wrong with having an editing tool only work with JavaScript if that is one of your concerns, as long as you provide a warning to end users that the tool requires JavaScript to work. (The difference between a publishing tool and an end user experience is you can be much more reliant on JavaScript.)

**For example:** Let's say you have a `<button>` that when clicked should add a new row to the form (in the production version of the form) and for whatever reason you do not want this functionality to be active in the preview version.

In that case in the preview / demo version of the form when you click this button an `alert` could be shown that says "will add a new row to the form".

That way screen reader users and keyboard only users can test the form without you needing to do too much extra work (and can also see if the form has usability issues for keyboard users while they are at it!)

I think this would be the most clear for everybody and a much better user experience.

You just need to think of navigating in and out of preview mode (<kbd>Esc</kbd> to close for example) and quick edits (when you preview the form give the option to focus the previously focused element if the forms are particularly long, keyboard only users will thank you for this! The same for when you go back to the edit, put focus back on the last edited item).

### Further reading

From an accessibility perspective WCAG isn't what you are looking for in this scenario, [Authoring Tool Accessibility Guidelines (ATAG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/atag/) is.

This is a little known set of guidance on how to create editors, WYSIWYGS etc. etc.

As with all W3C guidance it is a heavy read but if you understand the core principles it will guide you to good decisions and you can always ask here if you need clarity on some of the individual points that aren't clear :-).

---

---

### EDIT: How could you achieve an accessible interface with the current design

The issues that you have within the [codepen you linked](https://codepen.io/dwjohnston/pen/qBrGPmr?editors=1111) and their solutions are as follows:

#### Stop interactive items receiving focus

As you wrap each element you have correctly diagnosed your biggest issue which is nested interactive elements.

The solution to this is quite straight forward: Give every interactive element a `tabindex="-1"` as you said. This makes sure they cannot be focused incorrectly.

#### Make sure the actual wrapper item can be focused and activated

Then we just need to make sure that the wrapper `.content-item` has `tabindex="0"` so it is added to the focus order.

We also need to capture the <kbd>Enter</kbd> **and** the <kbd>Space</kbd> keys and ensure our panel is activated with them also.

##### Visual focus indicator

I also added an `outline` to the wrapper "button" so that visual focus indicators are available.

So that essentially fixes normal keyboard navigation issues, the next issue is how a screen reader will interpret nested buttons, inputs etc.

#### Screen reader corrections

Here I would also go simple, hide the button, input etc. entirely from a screen reader and instead explain what element is inside.

Effectively we make the button invisible and instead describe the contents of the `.content-item`.

To hide the element we use `aria-hidden="true"`

To announce something meaningful we can use some [`visually-hidden` (screen reader only) text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62109988/2702894) inside a `<span>`. This will be far more robust that using `aria-label` with such a complex application.

#### make the application behave well with a mouse

Final challenge - stop mouse events.

Luckily `pointer-events: none` has [really good support](https://caniuse.com/pointer-events) and even on the few browsers that don't support it being able to click into an input isn't the end of the world (we have fixed it for keyboard users)

#### Example with all issues resolved:

This solves all of the issues with your selection method.

Please note it doesn't take into account accessibility errors of the components themselves (for example the `<input>` having no `<label>` etc.) but I assume that is just because it is an example.

The only thing you need to work out is how to generate the visually hidden text describing the item and the `.content-info` "button" action.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
 
  const items = document.getElementsByClassName("content-item"); 
  const rightPanel = document.getElementById('right-panel');
  
  for (let i = 0; i< items.length; i++) {
    const item = items[i]; 
    
    item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      console.log(e.target);
      const id = e.target.dataset.id; 
      rightPanel.innerHTML = id; 

    });
  
  // ADDED this to capture the Enter and Space presses on our wrapper button
    item.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == "32" || e.keyCode == "13"){
      console.log(e.target);
         const id = e.target.dataset.id; 
         rightPanel.innerHTML = id; 
      }
    });
  
  }
});
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: row nowrap; 
  
}

.left {
  flex: 1 1 auto; 
}

.right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.content-item {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 600;
  border: solid 2px blue; 
  cursor: pointer;   
}

/* ADDED a focus indicator so keyboard users know where they are */
.content-item:focus{
    outline: 4px solid #333;
}

/* ADDED to stop pointer events reaching the input, button etc. */
input, button{
    pointer-events: none;
}

/* ADDED the visually hidden class so we can provide meaningful text to screen reader users */
.visually-hidden { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 - a 0 height clip, off to the bottom right of the visible 1px box */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px); /*maybe deprecated but we need to support legacy browsers */
    clip-path: inset(50%); /*modern browsers, clip-path works inwards from each corner*/
    white-space: nowrap; /* added line to stop words getting smushed together (as they go onto seperate lines and some screen readers do not understand line feeds as a space */
}
```

```html
<div class ="main"> 
  <div class ="left">
<!-- Added `tabindex="0"` so the wrapper is focusable by keyboard -->
<div class="content-item" role="button" data-id="item-1" tabindex="0">
  <!-- added `aria-hidden="true"` and `tabindex="-1"` to hide the input from screen readers and make sure it cannot be focused by keyboard, I also added `role="presentation"` just for good measure, although it shouldn't be needed. -->
  <input type="text" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" role="presentation">
  <!-- Added this span that explains the action that the "content-item button" would perform if clicked. You need to come up with something meaningful for the contents of this -->
  <span class="visually-hidden">Edit input [input identifier]</span>
</div>

<div class="content-item" role="button" data-id="item-2" tabindex="0">
  <button aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" `role="presentation"`> I am a button</button>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Edit button [button identifier]</span>
</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class ="right" > 
    
    <h2> Right panel</h2>
    <div id ="right-panel"> 
      
    </div>
    
  </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: You can use the readonly attribute on each control, use pointer: none and then disable keyups on any control. Then the labels are read and the user can tab but not change or interact with any of the fields. A text explanation in a paragraph can be linked to this form using labelledby to inform the screenreader user what's happening.

Comment: How would you test max length is implemented correctly as an example using that method? Or email validation? Not saying it isn't a possible / good solution (in which case why not add it as an answer) just wondering how that would be a better experience? It would be a similar amount of work to implement so just trying to see why you believe this is a better solution?

Comment: Or was this purely to point out the "How would that behave for a screen reader user?" could easily be solved this way instead of using `aria-hidden="true"` as that was a bit tongue-in-cheek way of saying the experience wouldn't be good that may have got lost in translation (I'm British so sarcasm is built-in!)

Comment: I'd love to answer this properly but don't have time at the moment. Think about your form not as just a form but a form with special fields for things like validations and properties. Normally a number control does read itself out, but if you want the user to know more then you can provide that; but you wouldn't once that form is live. You're giving the user an inside look on the form in a few ways they wouldn't see until they ran up into an error, for example. (I'm a yank in NZ so totally understand the royal humour. Ha. )

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into the `inert` attribute. It is not supported by any browser at the moment, but there are polyfill libraries.

The idea is that marking this on any element will make it and all its children non-interactive and invisible for accessibility purposes.

You can read some background and download the library here:

https://github.com/WICG/inert

Comment: beat me to it. Even tho it's an exotic use case, it is quite clearly a use case for inert.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var demoPage = $('div.demoPage');
demoPage.find('a').attr('href','#');
demoPage.find('button').attr("disabled", true)
  
})
```

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="no-copy">
    <p>You can't click me.</p>
</div> 
<div class="demoPage">
  
  <a href="www.google.com" readonly="" class="no-copy">
    It is a link
  
</a>
  
  <button> It is a button</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this addresses accessibility concerns, such as a button inside a button.

Comment: I edited my code, check out that, my JS disabled links and buttons!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--you can do this-->
<input type="text" id="input" disabled>
<script>
document.getElementById('input').disabled = true;
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that very simple by adding some css classes:

```
<div class="content-item disable-control" role="button" data-id="item-1">
  <input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="content-item disable-control" role="button" data-id="item-2">
  <button> I am a button</button>
</div>
```

^^ I added an additional "disable-control" class

```
.content-item.disable-control * {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: inherit;
  user-select: none;
}
.content-item.disable-control *::selection { 
  background: transparent;
}
```

Make sure to add some browser-specifix css if needed, e.g.

```
*::-moz-selection
```

.. and of course, you can modify my code to apply the class only once (for the whole left pane) and not for each control seperately

Answer (score -1):

Add the `disabled` attribute to all form elements that you want to disable.

Comment: From OP's question: *My fallback will likely be to disable all of the elements.* Your answer does not add anything useful here.