# CSS input element width going outside container

Tags: html, css

Why are the email and password widths going out of the `input-container` width?

```css
  form {
    background: #ccc;
  }
  .input-container {
    background: red;
    width: 469px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .usermail,
  .userpword {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  input,
  button {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #cacece;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  .username input {
    width: 206px;
  }
```

```html
<form action='' method='post' id='signupform'>
  <div class='input-container'>
    <div class='username'>
      <input type='text' name='fname' id='fname' placeholder='First Name'>
      <input type='text' name='lname' id='lname' placeholder='Last Name'>
    </div>
    <div class='usermail'>
      <input type='email' name='email' id='email' placeholder='Email'>
    </div>
    <div class='userpword'>
      <input type='password' name='pword' id='pword' placeholder='Password'>
    </div>
    <button>Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Because your padding does not count towards the width, so your input is `100% + padding` wide. use `box-sizing: border-box` to solve this issue. Also, the same applies to your border.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Input with width: 100% goes outside parent's bound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907518/css-input-with-width-100-goes-outside-parents-bound)

Comment: ^ Google "CSS Box Model"

Comment: Remember, a simple rule. `total width = width + padding + border`

Comment: Forgot about the padding effects. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you set padding. It will sum the value of the element width with the padding set.

To avoid this behavior, is recommended to add the property `box-sizing: border-box`

Example:

```
#element{
    box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Or even better:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Comment: Specifically, add it to the `input, button` CSS rule

Comment: Although 'even better' is a very loose definition as many will argue that using `*` wildcards is _bad_ for performance overall. Personally, I would not use the `*` as it turns the entire box model upside down, and everything you think you know now works differently, but that's personal preference.