# Div with display:table reserves 1px more

Tags: html, css

I have four div's

```
<div id="blockContainer">
    <div id="blockA">LogInR</div>
    <div id="blockB">Logo</div>
    <div id="blockC">Search</div>
    <div id="blockD">Post</div>
</div>
```

and style is:

```
#blockA {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#blockB {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    display: table-cell;
}
#blockC {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
#blockD {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

So my blockA with `width:100%` reserves `1px` more.

Comment: Explain your problem in your question please.

Comment: `1px` more than what? Try `box-sizing: border-box`, nut sure if this is what you mean.

Comment: what about another blocks, same issue? no idea what your issue, but maybe because of border: px ? btw, is your issue in all browsers? try to make border with 0px, does ur issue still exist.

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/783hzp

Comment: try to make it `table-cell`, or change css with without `table-cell` or `table` and just make div floating and give a widths, your structure is make no sense !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [width: 100%-padding?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5219175/1529630) or [Can I stop 100% Width Text Boxes from extending beyond their containers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/628500/1529630).

Comment: Aside: Using `table-cell` outside of a `table` is not a good practice. Although the specs say that it would create wrappers around itself.

Comment: @Abhitalks Using table-cell outside a table is not a bad practice. It will just generate an [anonymous one](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes).

Comment: @Oriol: Was editing my comment when yours came in! What I meant was if such divs are splattered across it would be confusing to find unintended layout results.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the way browsers compute the size of a box. It's adding the width of the border to the 100% width. You need to change the way it computes with `*{box-sizing: border-box;}`:

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
#blockA {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#blockB {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    display: table-cell;
}
#blockC {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
#blockD {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="blockContainer">
    <div id="blockA">LogInR</div>
    <div id="blockB">Logo</div>
    <div id="blockC">Search</div>
    <div id="blockD">Post</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Using width 100% and a border will make a 100% + border width element by default.  Try using box-sizing.

```css
#blockA, #blockB, #blockC, #blockD {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#blockA {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#blockB {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    display: table-cell;
}
#blockC {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
#blockD {
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="blockContainer">
    <div id="blockA">LogInR</div>
    <div id="blockB">Logo</div>
    <div id="blockC">Search</div>
    <div id="blockD">Post</div>
</div>
```