# 2 boxes of same height (percentage)

Tags: html, css

How to create two boxes (floating side by side) of same height.
I want to create boxes of height 40% of the container/window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**See the Example Here**](http://jsbin.com/avopi3)

---

*If that is what you are looking for, here is more:*

**CSS:**

```
  #parent{
    width:205px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    overflow:auto;
  }

  #child1{
    height:40%;
    background:#00ff00;
    float:left;
  }

  #child2{
    height:40%;
    background:#0000ff;
    float:left;
  }
```

**The Important Points:**

- The `float:left` is used to align the two boxes side-by-side
- The `height` is specified in `%` for both child boxes so that they inherit from their parent.

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">
        This is first box
    </div>
    <div id="child2">
        This is second box
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Got there before me! Good answer.+1

Answer (score 1):

This should be a simple solution for you. Here's my example:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/FQdye/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        More content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.left, .right
{
    float: left;
    width: 45%;a
    height: 40%;
    margin: 2%;
}

.left
{
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.right
{
    border: 1px solid #00f;
}
​
```

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have looking at it again.. I tend to use classes for most everything in case I have to repeat things in the document, you know how some clients are.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a % as height is relative to your parent container's height. Therefore you need to declare the height of your parent container. Take a look at this tutorial: [Equal Height Columns](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks).

Comment: Also, let me warn you ahead of time: CSS height is one of the trickier things to accomplish   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931187/css-metaphysics-why-is-page-vertical-alignment-so-difficult

Answer (score 0):

The question specifically mentions floating, and there have been several good answers for that, but I thought it might be worth posting [an answer that doesn't use floats](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/2boxes.html) in case the the mention of floating was accidental:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    outline: 1px solid #000;
}
.wrapper div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 198px;
    height: 40%;
    background: #66c;
}
.wrapper div:first-child {
    background: #6c6;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div>This is the first box</div>
    <div>This is the second box</div>
    <p>Some other content</p>
</div>
```

It doesn't currently work in WebKit, but I assume that's a bug and there'll be a workaround, I am investigating.  If you need it to work in IE < 8 add a conditional comment:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style>
    .wrapper div { zoom:1; *display:inline;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```