# Div margin-bottom of a proportion of its own height?

Tags: css

For example, I have a div that has a height of `100px` (I don't know the height, but let's suppose I did). I want to set the `margin-bottom` to a percent, so `25%` would be `25px` assuming the previous height. However, the percent seems to be of the document, not the element:

```
<div style="height:100px;margin-bottom:100%"></div>
```

The margin should be `100px` but it isn't, it is 100% of the height of the page.

The element is just a line of text that has no background, so using `height:150%` theoretically could also work.

Comment: Confirmed: http://jsfiddle.net/jghsF/

Comment: @JCOC Actually, the percentage is based on the page width, not height...

Comment: Oh well, then it's worse than I thought!

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others note, I don't know you can use CSS to do this. jQuery could help:

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/PZAvm/

```
<div id="margin">Foo</div>

div#margin {
    background-color:red;
    height:100px;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($('#margin').height());
    var margin = $('#margin').height()/4;
    $('#margin').css('margin-bottom',margin);
    alert($('#margin').css('margin-bottom'));
});
```

**EDIT** - This could possibly be done using em's.

**EDIT 2** - em's are keying off font size, not a calculated box model size. So it won't work.

**EDIT 3** - JCOC611 was able to use the em approach after all.

Original: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/xN9V7/3/

JCOC611's Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BCTg2/

The code:

```
<div id="foo">
    Foo
</div>
lol

div#foo {
    background-color: #fcc;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    font-size:20px
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the height is going to be changing a lot, so I was hoping for a CSS answer. (of course I could update the margin w/ javascript but that would just take too much code)

Comment: Who said the height would be changing by text wrapping?

Comment: I think that deriving the height for an element from a calculation that relies on width is not going to work (as Sime Vidas points out with his reference to the docs). If you could post an example of your usage with the html and your css, that might help device a solution with your specific needs in mind. Btw, I personally think it silly that margin-top and margin-bottom rely on the containing width. :\

Comment: Oop, nevermind. em's are keying off the font size, not margin, so when I updated the height, it still gave the same margin height.

Comment: It was your idea to use EM's, so if you update your answer to fit the fiddle I just posted, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: yes, because the margin will change depending on the font size

Comment: Ok, I updated it. Interesting how things work out sometimes. :)

Comment: This, however, will only work for one-line texts. Fortunately, that's my scenario. For anyone else, beware! PS: Yes it's pretty interesting! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 51):

How about a CSS3 solution:

```
div {        
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: translateY as a percentage seems to refer to the height of the element itself, not the height of its parent.

Comment: This question is not about the parent.

Comment: Your'e a genious! this should be the correct answer

Comment: this however does not affect surrounding elements like margin does. so it kind of acts like position relative. Can I use a transform that affects surrounding elements?

Comment: Great answer. Can't stand people using JS to solve all the layout problems CSS should be solving.

Comment: @mamashare nope, translate just moves the element, the occupied space is not being free tough. so, it is not a proper replacement for the margin property.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties

> Percentages:      refer to width of
>   containing block

If your DIV is in the BODY element, then the containing block is the BODY element, so the percentage will be based on the BODY width - which is in most cases the same as the width of the viewport.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jghsF/1/

(Try resizing the width of the browser window and you will see that the margin-bottom changes)

Comment: Using wrappers (which would be the solution) isn't really an option for me. So, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @JCOC I cannot tell for sure, there might be a CSS3 solution. Also, JavaScript (obviously).

Answer (score 1):

This question is a great deal more fascinating than I'd expected (**+1**).

I'm working with the following html structure:

```
<div id="someContent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Originally I tried to use padding to simulate a 'border' ([JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Xy8QF/)):

```
#someContent {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding: 10%;
}

p {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

This on the assumption that the `padding` would be derived from the height of the element itself, which turned out to be a *wrong*-assumption.

After that clearly failed I tried to use a margin on the contained elements, on the assumption that if the `margin` of the *containing* element is based on *its* parents, so too should the margin of the contained element, giving the following CSS:

```
#someContent {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 1em;
}

p {
    margin: 10%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Xy8QF/1/). And this failed, too.

I suspect that it's impossible without defining a `height` for the parent element, which might require a JS solution.

Comment: Thanks! JS is however my last resort, but you might want to check out the edit on my question, it might inspire something else!

Comment: No JS-solution, please! Think about people that have disabled JavaScript (there are some good reasons to disable it).

Comment: Well, my whole application relies on JS...:P