# Percentage height vs margin of parent element

Tags: css, layout, positioning

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pehrlich/dNLLa/

The child div has a height of 50% of its parent.  This confirms that the percentage-of-parent is working correctly.  (As per [Percentage Height HTML 5/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css))

That same div has a margin top.  If you change it to -50%; in the fiddle, you'll see that it moves completely out of view.  The percentage for the margin is being read relative to something else-- perhaps the .  It shouldn't be!

Comment: What `50%` are you talking about? I see none in the JSFiddle...

Comment: Oops. Here's the correct fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/pehrlich/dNLLa/1/

Comment: Well, that's expected behavior. I don't see the problem...

Comment: Compare that to this fiddle here, where 50% margin is a different distance than 50% height: http://jsfiddle.net/pehrlich/dNLLa/4/

Answer (score 0):

"The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1."

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties

[Div margin-bottom of a proportion of its own height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909724/div-margin-bottom-of-a-percent-of-the-height-of-itself#4909777)

JS it is.