# Scrollbar without fixed height/Dynamic height with scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="head">
        <p>Dynamic height without scrollbar</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Dynamic height with scrollbar</p>
    </div>
    <div id="foot">
        <p>Fixed height without scrollbar</p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I want to have the three parts inside the main part (#body) without overflow. So I need a scroll bar in the middle part.

I tried this CSS:

```
#content{
    border: red solid 1px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And this:

```
#content{
    border: red solid 1px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But neither of them work.

I made an example at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WAnd/).

Can I do this with only CSS and HTML? I'd prefer to avoid Javascript.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Flexbox is a modern alternative that lets you do this without fixed heights or JavaScript.

Setting `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` on the container and `flex-shrink: 0;` on the header and footer divs does the trick:

HTML:

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="head">
        <p>Dynamic size without scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size without scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size without scrollbar</p>  
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
        <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    </div>
    <div id="foot">
        <p>Fixed size without scrollbar</p>
        <p>Fixed size without scrollbar</p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    border: black dashed 2px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
    
#head {
    border: green solid 1px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

#content{
    border: red solid 1px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /*height: 100%;*/
}

#foot {
    border: blue solid 1px;
    height: 50px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Code snippet:

```css
#body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  border: black dashed 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#head {
  border: green solid 1px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

#content {
  border: red solid 1px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*height: 100%;*/
}

#foot {
  border: blue solid 1px;
  height: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="head">
    <p>Dynamic size without scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size without scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size without scrollbar</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
    <p>Dynamic size with scrollbar</p>
  </div>
  <div id="foot">
    <p>Fixed size without scrollbar</p>
    <p>Fixed size without scrollbar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this reply should be accepted as the answer for CSS3.

Comment: I think it's not the correct answer. It won't work without a fixed height for the body element.

Comment: @Equanox Limited height of the container is the point though, otherwise all three parts would simply expand vertically and there would be no need for scrollbars. Note that it can be a `max-height` instead of a fixed `height`.

Comment: You're still using a fixed height on the body.

Comment: wtf :D you have a fixed height

Comment: The point here is no fixed height on the `#content` element. The fixed height on the `#body` element is just to demonstrate that the `#content` div automatically shrinks when height is constrained, but you can just as well remove the fixed height from `#body`, or replace it with something like `max-height: 100%`.

Comment: Thanks for hint! Changing `flex-direction` from `row` to `column` solved my problem. Btw I do not need `flex-shrink: 0`.

Answer (score 25):

I have Similar issue with PrimeNG p_Dialog content and i fixed by below style for the contentStyle

```
height: 'calc(100vh - 127px)'
```

Comment: My favorite approach, but only if it didn't suck on mobile browsers with movable address bar. You'd need JS and do `window.innerHeight - 127px` to compensate for that :/

Answer (score 11):

Use this:

```
style="height: 150px; max-height: 300px; overflow: auto;"
```

fixe a height, it will be the default height and then a scroll bar come to access to the entire height

Comment: Scrolling only works when the height is set right? It doesn't work with `max-height` alone.

Comment: What is the purpose of setting `max-height` when you've already set a fixed `height`? This element will never not be 150 pixels tall unless overridden elsewhere, so what benefit is there in limiting its height to 300 pixels? Also, this answer uses a fixed height, which the question explicitly says it doesn't want.

Answer (score 10):

```
 <div id="scroll">
    <p>Try to add more text</p>
 </div>
```

here's the css code

```
#scroll {
   overflow-y:auto;
   height:auto;
   max-height:200px;
   border:1px solid black;
   width:300px;
 }
```

here's the demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xXJD25/wkpw8wcc/)

Answer (score 5):

You will have to specify a fixed height, you cannot use 100% because there is nothing for this to be compared to, as in `height=100%` of what?

Edited fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6WAnd/4/

Comment: you are right, it's not really 100% but I want the 3 div (head, content and foot) take 100% height of body part which has a fixed size.
I make an image for example : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/986131examplepanel.png

Comment: does your body or your head have a fixed height?

Comment: Only body have a fixed height. Head part must show all and in this case http://jsfiddle.net/6WAnd/11/, head overflows on the #content part

Comment: without JS you are going to find getting  two dynamic height sections above each other in a fixed body difficult!!

Comment: I think you are right, thid is not possible without JS. Thank for your help.

Comment: height=100% of another div, what's the problem?? Without it this plugin is useless. We need responsiveness

Comment: @Toolkit This was answered 3 years ago, things have most likely moved on by now...

Comment: yeah, plug in 100% height instead of your hard numbers, and the scroll content unrolls to full height, as if the overflow-y isn't there.  All the other solutions depend on actual numbers for the overall height or for the scroll area height.  I'm trying to make it fit into a container of unknown height.  Time to choose among ugly alternatives...

Comment: I got it.  I think that the outer .body's height depends on the inner .container's height, so you can't make the .container's height depend on the .body's height.  A number has to come from somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

extending @mtyaka answer of using flexbox,
if your scrollable is deep down in dom, need to use overflow: auto/hidden for all parent elements till we get a fixed height

jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rohilaharsh/cuazdnkh/1/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dynamic Container</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="one">
    One
        <div class="two">
    Two
            <div class="three">
      Three
                <div class="table">
          Table
                    <div class="header">Table Header</div>
                    <div class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure maiores corporis quisquam enim at nam earum non atque dolorum nulla quidem perferendis, porro eveniet! Quisquam, fugit ex aspernatur, aliquid necessitatibus amet aperiam pariatur facilis suscipit ea dolorum qui ratione assumenda eum minima. At a ullam magnam eveniet, hic sit quis dicta perferendis excepturi nemo voluptate ipsum doloremque expedita illo dolor voluptates culpa consequuntur quaerat porro reprehenderit ab alias! Maxime reprehenderit nihil doloribus exercitationem, cupiditate quasi dolorum voluptas repellendus vel fugit incidunt praesentium molestias modi numquam! Quo porro laudantium aperiam suscipit, molestiae quibusdam veniam cum nam fuga facere fugit quisquam distinctio!</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

html, body, .one,.two,.three,.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  /* important */
  overflow: hidden;
  
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

.body {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. Setting `*` to your settings helped clean up my stylesheet and simplify debugging `overflow: auto` issues n levels deep. I do set `flex: 1` on individual elements since that feels more controlled from a design perspective.

Answer (score 2):

A quick, clean approach using very little JS and CSS padding: http://jsfiddle.net/benjamincharity/ZcTsT/14/

```
var headerHeight = $('#header').height(),
    footerHeight = $('#footer').height();

$('#content').css({
  'padding-top': headerHeight,
  'padding-bottom': footerHeight
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With display grid you can dynamically adjust height of each section.

```
#body{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Add the above code and you will get desired results.

Sometimes when many levels of grids are involved css wont restrict your #content to 1fr. In such scenarios use:

```
#content{
  max-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got it right, but does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6WAnd/9/) solve your problem?

I just changed the `overflow-y: scroll;`

```
#content{
    border: red solid 1px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**Edited**

Then try to use percentage values like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6WAnd/19/

**CSS** markup:

```
#body {
    position: absolute;
    top; 150px;
    left: 150px;
    height: 98%;
    width: 500px;
    border: black dashed 2px;
}    
#head {
    border: green solid 1px;
    height: 15%;
}
#content{
    border: red solid 1px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 70%;
}
#foot {
    border: blue solid 1px;
    height: 15%;
}
```

Comment: But I can't set the size for #head and #content.
I would like #content and #head fill all the main div (#body).
I just make an image to illustrate it : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/986131examplepanel.png

Comment: This soluion don't permit to have 2 blocks with dynamic height. If I put a lot of text in the first part, it don"t work : http://jsfiddle.net/6WAnd/21/. 

I think @philip-bevan has found that is not possible without JS. See his answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
#head {
    border: green solid 1px;
    height:auto;
}    
#content{
            border: red solid 1px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height:150px;       
        }
```

Comment: It's work unless if I change the first part.
Try with a lot of "<p>Dynamic size without scrollbar</p>"

http://jsfiddle.net/EKvCw/