# I have three stacked elements inside a fixed div, but third will not overflow: scroll correctly?

Tags: html, css, position, overflow

Okay, please see here - jsfiddle.net/c4df54xg/

.. the third element needs to be within the container (not overlapping like it is) and the text content should have a scroll bar so the rest can be viewed. I cant understand why not and I cant work out how to get around it.

Not sure if im having an off day or what but Im sure I have done something like this before..

Thank you all in advance for your time! Ash.

[UPDATE]

I forgot to mention, the height needs to be dynamic so it scales devices properly and preferably without JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add height for it. Example:

```
`#test #inner div {
    overflow: scroll;
    border: solid yellow;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to mention, the height needs to be dynamic so it scales devices properly and preferably without JS.

Comment: @Ash then you must read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980822/scrollbar-without-fixed-height-dynamic-height-with-scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

overflow goes onto the container of the element that will be overflowing.

```
#test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid green;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c4df54xg/1/

Comment: Argh, I was hoping to only have the text div itself have a scroll.

Comment: @Ash Do you know the height of the header + video?
http://jsfiddle.net/c4df54xg/4/

Answer (score 0):

### Table [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c4df54xg/5/) (IE9+)

```
#inner{
  position:static;
  height:100%;
  display:table;
}


#test #inner .text-wrapper {
  display:table-row;
  bottom:0;
  border: solid yellow;
  height:100%;
}

#test #inner .text {
  display:block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height:100%;
}
```

### Flexbox [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c4df54xg/2/) (CSS3)

Set the container to `display:flex` and the child that you want to flex to `flex:1`

```
#inner{
  position:static;
  height:100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  justify-content: flex-start; /* align items in Main Axis */
  align-items: stretch; /* align items in Cross Axis */
  align-content: stretch; /* Extra space in Cross Axis */
}

.flexbox-item.footer{
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .1);
    flex: 1; /* same as flex: 1 1 auto; */
}
```

Comment: I did look at this but I need to support IE9 :-( Okay, so you think JS it is?

Comment: @Ash It seems like it's doable with `display:table` and `display:table-row`. Check the edit. It requires to wrap the text in another div. Hope it works on IE9