# Div element height 100% with vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck trying to figure this out.  Basically I have a div containing lots of individual divs (see image)

[image]

but I can get the vertical scroll bar to work properly when I use height: 100%;

Example:

```js
$('#active-panel-container').on('scroll', function(e) {
  alert('scrolling');
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative;">
  <div id="active-panel-container" style="height:100%;overflow-y:scroll;  margin: 0 auto;">
    panel divs go in here
  </div>
</div>
```

using height: 100% in the div active-panel-container doesnt seem to work and execute the scroll event.  But if I put an actual height like 700px in active-panel-container, the scroll event works and the scroll bar is active:

[image]

I have the first div with the relative position because I also have another div along with the panel to show status.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I've been trying to figure this out for some time now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrollbar without fixed height/Dynamic height with scrollbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980822/scrollbar-without-fixed-height-dynamic-height-with-scrollbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give `height:100%` to parent div of `#active-panel-container` too.

```js
$('#active-panel-container').on('scroll', function(e) {
  console.log('scrolling');
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative;height:100%;">
  <div id="active-panel-container" style="height:100%;overflow-y:scroll;  margin: 0 auto;">
    panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here panel divs go in here 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG I had a parent field wrapping the code above that I didnt notice.  Your code sample help clear it up.  Thanks so much