# Change scrollbar height

Tags: css

I would like to know if it's possible to change scrollbar height like this image:

[image]

I tried with

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {max-height: 50%; height: 50%;}
```

Or

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {max-height: 50%; height: 50%;}
```

But nothing happened

---

Thank

Comment: did you try on other browser?

Comment: You would probably need to use some sort of scrollbar plugin

Comment: I can't use plugin to do that, I think it's not possible to change height

Comment: Hope this helps  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980822/scrollbar-without-fixed-height-dynamic-height-with-scrollbar

Comment: No sorry, I haven't solutions

Comment: What you can do is, you can make `overflow:hidden` on the parent `div`, and make a `div` inside that parent, make `overflow:scroll` in that `div` and adjust the `height` accordingly.

Comment: @Code_Ninja Yes it's possible but it reduces the content height and I can't see all informations

Comment: for that you need to adjust the layout accordingly, for example, you might need to increase the font size of the text and then height of the div upto the stars. You might also need to reduce the margin to 0. Like that, try and adjust because I dont think there is anyway by which we can reduce the height of a scrollbar. It has to be displayed till the full height of the div that is to be scrolled.

Comment: by this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3pqe67mr/5/) you can customize the scrollbar but I haven't found a way to customize the height of a scroll bar yet.

Comment: I saw many links to custom scrollbar but not height

Answer (score 117, accepted):

It is possible.
The first thing you need to know is the structure of a scroll bar. Here I reference a picture from [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/).

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar              { /* 1 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-button       { /* 2 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track        { /* 3 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  { /* 4 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        { /* 5 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       { /* 6 */ }
::-webkit-resizer                { /* 7 */ }
```

[image]

to achieve what you want, you need:

- change where 5(scrollbar thumb) start to scroll and stop scrolling
- fake a scroll track instead of 3.

```css
.page { 
  position: relative;
  width: 100px; 
  height: 200px;
}

.content {
   width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  padding: 0; 
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  overflow-x: hidden; 
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.page::after { 
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  top: 10px;
  right: -1px;
  width: 5px;
  background: #666;
}

.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
}
.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}
    
.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: red;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
}

.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:end {
    background: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
    background: transparent;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content">
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for a good finding! Another way that doesn't involve a pseudoelement is to use background-image and linear-gradient on `-webkit-scrollbar-track`.

Answer (score 35):

All you need to do is:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a very good solution, primarily because it only visually shrinks the button but does not actually change the height in the calculation of scrolling so you wind up with a scroll wheel that stops mid way

Comment: Working perfectly! Thanks.! Scrolling as it should even with a large margin set.

Answer (score 3):

the default code for height of scrollbar

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 0px; //for horizontal scrollbar
  height: 0px; //for vertical scrollbar
}
```

increase the width and height of both simultaneously having same value to adjust the height of scrollbar

```
-----------------
|              ||
|              ||
|              ||
|              ||
|              ||
|              ||
|______________||
```

if you want to decrease the height of scrollbar then use

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 50px; //for horizontal scrollbar
  height: 50px; //for vertical scrollbar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Create the custom cursor and cursor -->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Center the div</title>

    <style>
       body{
        /* Solution */
            cursor: url(cursor.png),default;
            
            /* Customizing the scrollbar */


       }
      
/* Solution to scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 30px;
   
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    
    width: 30px;
   background-color: red;
   border-radius: 30px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-button{
 
}








      *{
            margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
        }


        .parent{
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.555);
       
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;

        }
        .child{
           width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: green;
            border-radius: 30px;
           
        }
        .parent-1{
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(48, 168, 0, 0.555);
   
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="parent-1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```