# How to horizontally center the first item in a inline-block list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a list item set to be overflow-x scroll so that user can scroll horizontally to view the content. I don't have an issue creating all that but I need to make the following:

1. Make the first item in the list to be always starting center horizontally, ie it will be center like the text block. I've tried all ways with css, using flex-box and etc but it will cause the whole scroll content to be center rather than just the first item. Even tried bootstrap offset but of no luck as when view on the different screen size it won't center.

Currently what it look like
[image: Current]

What I want to achieve.
[image: What I want to achieve]

2. Another issue is since my horizontal scroll currently is like Image 1. Is there any way I can also make the scrollbar to be showing in the center rather than taking the whole scrollable width but user can scroll the content like the image below?

[image]

Any kind suggestion guys? Seems like I can't just use CSS and need JS but my JS is... horrible. I'll be happy to pay for a working solution if need too. Kind of desperate now.

Thanks in advance.

I've created the codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EqwZLJ

```
.scroll-horizontal ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.scroll-horizontal ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 735px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.scroll-horizontal {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.overflow-x {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.overflow-x::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.overflow-x::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 11px;
}

.overflow-x::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 11px;
}

.overflow-x::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid white; /* should match background, can't be transparent */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}


 <div class="text-center" style="width: 750px; margin: 50px auto;"><p>I need the first image in the list to be position center with the text content. I need the first image in the list to be position center with the text content. I need the first image in the list to be position center with the text content. I need the first image in the list to be position center with the text content. I need the first image in the list to be position center with the text content. I need the first image in the list to be position center with the text content. </p></div>


<div class="overflow-x space-default scroll-horizontal">
        <div class="row flex-row flex-nowrap">
            <div class="col-12">
                <ul class="">
                    <li><img src="https://ultraimg.com/images/2016/08/11/1V6u.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="https://ultraimg.com/images/2016/08/11/1V6u.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="https://ultraimg.com/images/2016/08/11/1V6u.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="https://ultraimg.com/images/2016/08/11/1V6u.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jquery in your web? if yes then you can try use this.

> Jquery

```
let mainEle = $(".scroll-horizontal"); // this is scrollable div id
let firstImageEle = $("#image-1");
mainEle.scrollLeft(firstImageEle[0].offsetLeft);
```

> Javascript

```
let mainEle = document.getElementsByClassName("scroll-horizontal")[0]; // this is scrollable div id
let firstImageEle = document.getElementById("image-1"); // first image div id
mainEle.scrollLeft(firstImageEle.offsetLeft);
```

> Add blank space

```
<ul class="">
    <li id="image-blank" style="width: 735px;height: 459px;"></li>
    <li id="image-1"><img src="https://ultraimg.com/images/2016/08/11/1V6u.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://ultraimg.com/images/2016/08/11/1V6u.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://ultraimg.com/images/2016/08/11/1V6u.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://ultraimg.com/images/2016/08/11/1V6u.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""></li>
 </ul>
```

Please check your code pen. I have change it for you.

Comment: Hi @William Gunawan, thank you for your fast respond, sorry, I didn't realised I forgot to include the codes and etc. I've better explain my need with codepen above. I also try your suggestion but nothing happen.

Comment: Please check this code pen for applied solution. https://codepen.io/williamgunawan22/pen/pMWevQ?editors=1111

Comment: Hi @William Gunawan, thank you for your effort. What I want to achieve when the page first load will be like my second image above and when people start to scroll, it will look like my third image above. Currently, the solution you suggested is just to center the whole content div which I can achieve but not something I have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://codepen.io/pi-L/pen/KOXmvz) is a forked version of your pen.
For the centering part i created a `container-grid` of 3 columns (seemed to be the easiest way):

**Edit after comment :**
I used `%` instead of `px`.

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33%);
}
```

For sizing the images i did the same :

```
.scroll-horizontal li {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 33%;
}

.scroll-horizontal .img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

To display the first image in the middle, i just added a margin the size of the first column :

```
.scroll-horizontal li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 33%;
}
```

And concerning the scroll bar i would like for this to work, but for now it doesn't :

```
.space-default::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:end {
  margin-right: 33%;
}

.space-default::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
  margin-left: 33%;
}
```

So i opted to hide it altogether (doesn't work in firefox) :

```
.space-default::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Otherwise for scrollbar styling, you can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817727/change-scrollbar-height) or [this article](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/), even though it only work for webkit browsers.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Hi @Pierre-Yves, thank you so much for your help, your solution is very close but I need the images to be able to overflow both of the left and right when the user scroll through them. So when user scroll it will look like image number 3 (item 2). Right now it gets hidden when scrolling to the left.

Answer (score -1):

float:right; to the divs needing to right align?

Answer (score -1):

add all the images div inside one new div and try by giving it center alignment or you can use grid system

Comment: Please add some code to demonstrate your solution works.