# Hide scroll bar on a popup element

Tags: html, css

I have a popup element that has rounded corners with `border-radius` and a stylized scrollbar. My question is if there is a way to hide the overflow of the scrollbar so that when the user is at the top of the popup it won't be overflowing like in this

[image]

(white line is the scroll bar, red is the background and the popup is dark)

Comment: can you share your code to us?

Comment: It's just a box with border-radius. and the scroll bar has width and height of 5px and changed colors. Made a codepen [Codepen](https://codepen.io/xgffyse/pen/WNyNrep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` properties to your `.box::-webkit-scrollbar-track`. This way you reduce the available space of the scrollbar-track from top and bottom:

```css
.box::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

You can read more about all CSS scrollbar properties [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817727/change-scrollbar-height) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/).

---

Here's a working snippet:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(207, 35, 35);
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-parent {
  margin: 50px;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 550px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.box::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}

.box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.box::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-parent">
  <div class="box">
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
    <br> text
  </div>
</div>
```