Scrollbar position for Heatmap with column and row labels
In my current implementation the row label and column labels next to the heatmap are also inside the scrollable container. Because of this the scrollbar does not only cover the heatmap itself, but is wider and longer and include


css:


.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
    grid-tempalte-rows: 100px auto;
} 

.col-labels {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 2;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: grey;
}

.row-labels{
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 1000px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: grey;
}

.corner{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: sticky;
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 20;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.heatmap{
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 2;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: blue;
}
html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="corner">
  </div>

  <div class="col-labels">
    Those are the column labels above the heatmap
  </div>

  <div class="row-labels"> 
    Those are the row labels next to the heatmap 
  </div>

   <div class="heatmap">
    This is the heatmap
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>



s both the column and row labels.
Expected behavior:
Only the actual heatmap (without column and row labels) has the scrollbars along side of it. The row and column labels should still scroll along when scrolling the heatmap.
https://heatmap-grid.w3spaces.com/heatmap-scrollbar.html

As your grid is just 2 rows and 2 columns due to that you just need very few css to achieve that, you can refer to the below code snippet. Thanks


.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.corner {
  background-color: white;
}

.col-labels {
  background-color: silver;
}

.row-labels {
  background-color: grey;
}

.heatmap {
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: scroll;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Rotated Blue Line</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="corner"></div>
    <div class="col-labels">
      Those are the column labels above the heatmap
    </div>
    <div class="row-labels">Those are the row labels next to the heatmap</div>
    <div class="heatmap">
      This is the heatmap.  VERY_VERY_VERY_LONG_TEXT_JUST_TO_MOCK_SCROLL_X_VERY_VERY_VERY_LONG_TEXT_JUST_TO_MOCK_SCROLL_X_VERY_VERY_VERY_LONG_TEXT_JUST_TO_MOCK_SCROLL_X_VERY_VERY_VERY_LONG_TEXT_JUST_TO_MOCK_SCROLL_X_
                Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It
                has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it
                over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
                Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure
                Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through
                the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
                undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
                of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by
                Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of
                ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem
                Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
                1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random
                text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC,
                making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
                Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure
                Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through
                the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
                undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
                of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by
                Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of
                ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem
                Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
                1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random
                text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC,
                making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
                Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure
                Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through
                the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
                undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
                of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by
                Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of
                ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem
                Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
                1.10.32.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.
Unfortunately with your implementation, when I scroll the blue heatmap, the row and column labels do not scroll along with the heatmap but instead stay stationary.
My goal is that the column and row labels should be connected to the heatmap (like in my example: https://heatmap-grid.w3spaces.com/heatmap-scrollbar.html) but the scrollbar should not go beyond the heatmap -> like in your solution.

@JonasBlum okay, got it i guess you are simply trying to set the custom height & width for the scroll bars which i don't think is directly possible(not sure if that can be done using JS), even if you find some way to acheive that then you may face issues with supporting it in all the major browser/ devices, can refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817727/change-scrollbar-height
