# overflow auto with no height in flex

Tags: css

I have some complex layout with flex.

**Default Layout**

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}

.root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 80px;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column>.head {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: white;
}

.column>.body {
  overflow: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: skyblue;
}

.fixed {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <header>

  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="column" style="flex-grow:6;background:yellow">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="column" style="flex-grow:6;background:pink">
            <div class="head">Head</div>
            <div class="body">
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column" style="flex-grow:4;background:lime"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fixed"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="flex-grow:4;background:orange">

      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

</div>
```

You can see the `skyblue` space in my code.

Many `<p>` will be in the `skyblue` space.

So it is gonna be overflowed like this.

I want to make it scroll when it is overflowed.

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}

.root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 80px;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column>.head {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: white;
}

.column>.body {
  overflow: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: skyblue;
}

.fixed {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <header>

  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="column" style="flex-grow:6;background:yellow">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="column" style="flex-grow:6;background:pink">
            <div class="head">Head</div>
            <div class="body">
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column" style="flex-grow:4;background:lime"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fixed"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="flex-grow:4;background:orange">

      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

</div>
```

**condition**

I don't want to declare the `height` of `skyblue` space.

body's height should be `100vh` but in this code `400px`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980822/scrollbar-without-fixed-height-dynamic-height-with-scrollbar Take a look here, you may found something you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex: 1 0 0;` to `.column>.body` and you will have `skyblue` space scroll in overflow.

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}

.root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 80px;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column>.head {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: white;
}

.column>.body {
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0; /* Change from flex-grow:1  to flex: 1 0 0 */
  background: skyblue;
}

.fixed {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <header>

  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="column" style="flex-grow:6;background:yellow">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="column" style="flex-grow:6;background:pink">
            <div class="head">Head</div>
            <div class="body">
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
              <p>This space should be overflow auto</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column" style="flex-grow:4;background:lime"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fixed"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="column" style="flex-grow:4;background:orange">

      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

</div>
```

Comment: @eddy I have seen ROOT has answered your question. Instead of using a negative value of `bottom`, you may use a positive value of `top` to position in the `.custom-tooltip`. E.g. `top: 4rem` Since you use `rem` in `.button-container`, you may use back the same unit for the positioning in the `.custom-tooltip`.

Answer (score 1):

Try playing around with `max-height`.

```css
.column>.body {
    max-height: 450px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    background: skyblue;
}
```