# Unwanted vertical scrollbar and overlapping text

Tags: html, css

Scrollbars disappear when border is removed, and I've tried experimenting with margins and padding, but to no avail.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWHAQ/) (In FF, Opera and Chrome, h1's background isn't white, but it *is* in JSFiddle, in all three.)

**(X)HTML 5:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is just a title for kicks</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/whoopie.css"
media="all" />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <!--Content starts here. Nonsensical comment ends in 3...2...-->
    <h1 class ="header" dir="ltr">Here... be... <a href="images">Images!</a></h1>

    <p class="middle" dir="ltr" lang="en-GB"
            title="Explanatory title">
                    Tidbit of info</p>
    <p class="btw" dir="ltr" lang="en-GB" title="Funny title?">
            No, no joke here "/
    <br>
    <br>More text
    <br>
    <br>Even more text
    <br>And yes, these are meant to be on seperate lines.
    <br>
    <br>This is the final line</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS3:**

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    color: black;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border: 1.2em inset #000;
    font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 6.25em;
    margin: 0;
}

.middle {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
}

.btw {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Vertical scrollbar. How can I get rid of it, but still have one appear when viewport gets too short? (window is resized to be smaller/less tall)
2. Overlapping text. How can I prevent it from happening when viewport gets too short?
3. Opera. Is there a way to make the empty space underneath the bottom border disappear? (again: with shorter viewports)

Answer (score 2):

For the full height see this answer
[CSS 100% height with padding/margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin/3037901#3037901)

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    color: black;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border: 1.2em inset #000;
    font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;

/* Note these below*/
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RWHAQ/1/

Answer (score 2):

It is the `html { height:100%; border:1.2em }` that is causing it.  The border is cumulative with (i.e. adds to) the height.  If you change the border to "none" then the scrollbar disappears.

- [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)