# Fixed bottom margin

Tags: css, html, margin

I've a page like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  #mainDiv{
  height: 100%;
  }

  #myDiv{
  overflow: auto;
  width: 400px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="myDiv">content</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wish `mainDiv` was entirely contained in the screen (without scrollbars). This div contains `myDiv` and `myDiv` height depends on the screen height in such a way that its bottom border has a 30px margin from the screen bottom (or `mainDiv` bottom).
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Johno suggested the solution should be

```
#mainDiv { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding-bottom: 30px; }
#mydiv { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

but when you try this solution you get a scrollbar because the content height is bigger than that of the window.

You get this because I think that the margin is added to the height of the content (that is 100%). So the order of the rules evaluation is:

1. Set the content height to 100%
2. Add a border of 30 px to the current height.

I tried to set a fixed height to the content, that is the window height minus 30 px, and I got the correct result.

Comment: Yes, I think too. But I can't use a fixed height in px, calculated according to my window size. I wish something like `100%-30px` so there will be a 30px border in any screen, but unfortunately css doesn't accept this kind o measure.

Comment: I found a duplicate question. Here you are a correct answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/485887/680740. I tried and I think it's what you are looking for.

Comment: I didn't found this answer and it works perfectly. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
#mainDiv {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
#mydiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

HTML

```
   <div id="mainDiv">
       <div id="mydiv">content</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
#mainDiv { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding-bottom: 30px; }
#mydiv { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

The padding of `#mainDiv` should give the effective margin that you're hoping for on `#mydiv`.

To make sure there are no scroll bars, you may need to remove padding etc from the `body` too.

Comment: With this code I've a 30px margin "under" the screen bottom, so there's the scrollbar... Can you explain me again your suggestion?