# What might cause this "blank" area?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a bug that when accessing a specific page, the bottom of the page is blank:

[image]

I checked with FireBug and the blank area is just empty, no HTML code at all.

My question is: what might cause this kind of problem? It occurs on Firefox, Chrome, IE latest version. Thank you.

EDIT: as my answer mentioned, this caused when applying a background image to a form, instead to the body

Comment: Actually, your screen height is more than your html page.

Comment: You can use CSS "trick" to make your main `<div>` span the whole height. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin) and here is [live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/xNgKF/) of this.

Comment: I'm not sure if I interpreted your question correctly when I come to think of it.. If you highlight the area that you consider to be "blank" it would be easier to help.

Comment: You're asking for guesses, which is not efficient for you (in getting an answer) or for us (in providing one). Try making a http://jsfiddle.net/ / http://jsbin.com/ test case, or at least linking to the live site.

Answer (score 1):

It's blank because you haven't filled it with content. If you want the footer to be placed at the bottom, you could read up on http://www.alistapart.com/articles/footers/