# body height not filling 100% page height

Tags: html, css

I can't figure this one out. I've got a simple set of divs with a header, sidebar and content area. The header is full width, the side and content are floated left.

I need the sidebar (for the background) to fill 100% of the page height, but when I inspect element in chrome, the `<body>` is actually ending long before the bottom of the page, which seems to be limiting the height of my sidebar.

What is keeping the `<body>` from filling the full page here?

```
    ​<body>
    <div id="head">
    </div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/dashboard.php"><img src="/img/blank.png" alt="home" id="home_ico">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="admin"><a><img src="/img/blank.png" alt="home" id="users_ico">Users</a>
                    <ul class="submenu" style="display: none;">
                        <li><a href="/users">Manage users</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/users/add.php">Add a user</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class=""><a><img src="/img/blank.png" alt="home" id="clients_ico">Clients</a>
                    <ul class="submenu" style="display: none;">
                        <li><a href="/client_orgs">Manage clients</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/client_orgs/add.php" class="admin">Add a client</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


                <li class=""><a><img src="/img/blank.png" alt="home" id="projects_ico">Projects</a>
                    <ul class="submenu" style="display: none;">
                        <li><a href="/projects">Manage projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/projects/add.php" class="admin">Create a project</a></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li><a href="/projects/submitted.php" class="admin client">Submitted projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/projects/closed.php" class="admin">Closed projects</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class=""><a href="/my_account"><img src="/img/blank.png" alt="home" id="account_ico">Account</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active"><a href="/help.php"><img src="/img/blank.png" alt="help" id="help_ico">Help</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>    
<div id="body" class="full">
  <div id="content">

    <!--start block-->
    <div class="block">
        <h1><img src="/img/blank.png" alt="home" id="help_ico"> Help</h1>
        <p>
        Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.
        </p>
    </div>  
</div>   
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html, body {
    height:100%;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 160%;
    position: relative;
    background: #000;
}
#sidebar{
    width: 200px;
    background: #000;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -4px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        box-shadow: inset -4px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     float: left;
}
#body{
    float: left;
    padding: 30px 0 30px 40px;
    width: 75%;
}
```

Comment: Helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Looks like you have `float:left` applied on your children. Use this code :

```
html, body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem; its so annoying.. I tried the overflow but it did not work... Can you take a look http://omarhabash.com/wp/?page_id=54.

Comment: You should have a gold medal for this answer, I was searching for ages! Thanks.

Comment: This has made inner scroll bars appear!

Answer (score 24):

Please use this answer wisely, I't could help in many cases:

```
html, body{min-height:100%;}
body{height:100vh;}
```

Comment: Thanks worked fine for me but can you tell what is VH?

Comment: VH means: View port Height. 
Each (1vh) = (1%) from the view port height. Link below will explain it very well:
https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/

Comment: This will force the page size to `100vh` **only**. If your content is bigger than `100vh`, this will cause issues. This solution will only work if you know your content only stretches up to `100vh`.

Comment: should be:
```
html,
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

try adding

```
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

When in doubt - the best way I found to tackle this is by adding:

```
html { overflow-y:scroll; }
```

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this will help anyone but I had the same problem but only on mobile. I discovered that there was a style `html { height: 100%; }` that was causing the body to not extend the full height. Once I removed the 100% height on the html tag it fixed the body not extending the full height of the page on mobile. I still have 100% height on the body tag.

Comment: That was it for me, I don't know how it works, but I think the height of `html` was being constrained by the window viewport size on first load of the page.

Comment: This worked for me too. Great!

Comment: Rather the opposite worked for me - I had to apply 
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%;"> and it worked...

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be trying to achieve a layout which spans the entire height of the container - these layouts are not posible. You should read up on the [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) CSS technique, a common workaround to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

**First:**
The width of your elements is greater than 100% of the width of the page
This is why your **div id="body"** is getting stuck below the sidebar.

Try making the width of the body something like 30% and you should see what I mean.

**Second:**
*height:100%* does not really work the way it would seem there are workarounds for this.
 [Here is a great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin)

Comment: I tried that, putting a clear inside the body and inside the `content` div and inside the `body` div and it had no effect

Comment: I had a chance to take a closer look at your code and updated my answer.  take a look at let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score -1):

For me, I had to add `margin-bottom: -2em` to the container in my SPA where backend + frontend files meet