# Including margin for width and height

Tags: css

I want box width and height to include all of the content, padding, border width, and margin by default. Is there a way to do this? Especially, I want to be able to specify something like `width: 100%` including everything up to the margin.

Comment: None box-sizing value includes margin size. `border-box` includes everything but margin: 
**The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when the document is in Quirks mode.**

Comment: You're trying to include to width/height as much as possible, `padding-box` includes the padding size only, and `border-box` includes the padding and border so `border-box` is closer to your requirements.

Comment: @AlecTMH Okay. I was interpreting `padding-box` in a wrong way. You are right.

Comment: This was a big help for me, box size is boxwidth+padding+border (but not margin): insert in CSS: *, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}

Comment: I think if you are using a DIV. which by default a display:block element will include all the things within container. can you tell where do you want to use exactly?

Comment: @sawa, you should get very familiar with this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS 100% height with padding/margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin)

Answer (score 37):

This is a vague question, but I'll answer the best I can.

Margin, by definition, is the area around the outside of your box; meaning there's no way to include margins inside of your div.

If you would like more padding on the inside of your box, but you don't want the box to resize, then use: `box-sizing:content-box;`

Or if you would like to include padding **and** the border, use: `box-sizing:border-box;`

A workable solution that preserves the size of your divs and removes overflow would look something like this:

```
#parent{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    padding:2em;
}
#child{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:1em;
}
```

---

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Just place the div you want to give margins to inside of another div that has padding. Thus creating faux margins.

Comment: Yes, adding another DIV around is probably the only way to get this done. You may still use `margin` for the inner element (may require `box-sizing: border-box` if borders are used and `width: 100%` shall be set), if the desired width is set to the outer element.

Comment: it is the issue when you want clean code, many divs in row, each with background image. you want some specific gaps between, only solution is flex or wrap it in another div which in my opinion should be absolutely unnecessary

Answer (score 30):

if your margin is for example **10px** you can use

```
width: calc(100% - 20px);
box-sizing: border-box;
```

[browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

[w3schools.com reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp)

Comment: you can do `width: calc(100% - 0);` for any size margin

Answer (score 7):

Set the CSS `box-sizing` property to `border-box` to make `width` and `height` include the content, border, and padding. This allows you to set `width: 100%` and still add `padding` or `border`. In other words `box-sizing: border-box` makes `width` include everything between the inner edges of the margin. There is no way to include the margin itself in such a way.

```
.example { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; padding: 10px }
```

#### Useful references

- [CSS Box Model visualization](http://ryanve.com/css/box-model/)
- [CSS3 UI: `box-sizing` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing)
- [`* { box-sizing: border-box }` FTW](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Comment: border-box doesn't seem to help in my case, when I applied it to the body element in attempt to allow height: 100vh size the body to the page without scroll bars. The scroll bars still happened.

Comment: Not sure why this is voted down, it would seem to be the most sensible way to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe wrap another div around it and specified that div's width?

```html
<div style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid blue;">
<div style="width: 100px; background:yellow; margin: 10px; border: 1px solid blue">
inner width 100px not including it's margin.
</div>
</div>

<div style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid blue">
<div style="background:yellow; margin: 10px; border: 1px solid blue">
  inner width's 100px including it's margin.
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex;` for the parent tag.

For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.center {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;   /* it can put children in one line */
}

.left {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.right {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works well if you have the possibility to split your content into rows explicitly via HTML